# @ in java string instead of backslashes

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raw Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256667/raw-strings-in-java)

In C# there is such a thing as @ ("at sign") that can be put before string if forbidden symbols occurs. For example:

```
@"a\b\c"
```

In java I have to put backslashes

```
"a\\b\\c"
```

Is there any way in Java to make this easier?

Comment: what's wrong with escaping via backslashes?

Comment: @mfrankli It is error prone and uncomfortable. Just have a look at the regex in java cluttered with backslashes. I love java but this is a nice feature I miss.

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be use equvivalent code for the symbols you want to escape.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. I have made the transition not long ago and at first was constantly looking for "what is C#'s equivalent in Java for xyz?"

This is sometimes helpful but mostly frustrating. C# is a much more advanced language than Java and it will take a long time for Java to catch up.

You get used to it over time :-)