# Regular expression not working despite testing

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to enforce validation of an ID that includes the first two letters being letters and the next four being numbers, there can be one 0 i.e. 0333 but can never be full zeroes with 0000 therefore something like ID0000 is not allowed. The expression I came up with seems to check out when testing it online but doesn't seem to work when trying to enforce it in the program:

```
\b(?![A-Z]{2}[0]{4})[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}\b
```

and heres the code I'm currently using to implement it:

```
String pattern = "/\b(?![A-Z]{2}[0]{4})[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}\b/";
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String ingID = ingredID.getText().toString();
Matcher m = regEx.matcher(ingID);

if (m.matches()) {
    ingredID.setError("Please enter a valid Ingrediant ID");
}
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to validate correctly with accepting ids like ID0000 when it shouldn't be. Any thoughts folks ?

Comment: Should it be `\\b` in the String?

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: The `/` is a regex string delimiter. So you shouldn't have both `/` and `"`. Past that, it depends on what language you're using--what is this?

Comment: @KyleStrand It looks like Java

Comment: it would be Java indeed

Comment: Mkay, expanding my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to `"\\b(?![A-Z]{2}[0]{4})[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}\\b"`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is essentially that Java isn't all that Regex-friendly; you need to deal with the limitations of Java strings in order to create a string that can be used as a Regex pattern. Since `\` is the escape character in Regex *and* the escape character in Java strings (and since [there's no such thing as a raw string literal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256667/raw-strings-in-java-for-regex-in-particular)), you must *double-escape* anything that must be escaped in the Regex in order to create a literal `\` character within the Java string, which, when parsed as a Regex pattern, will be correctly treated as the escape character.

So, for instance, the Regex pattern `/\b/` (where `/`, as mentioned in my comment, delimits the pattern itself) would be represented in Java as the *string* `"\\b"`.