# How to create a String with containing escape sequences in java without using StringEscapeUtils Class?

Tags: java, string, stringescapeutils

I want to store `"~ s/\n|\s+|.*?=|;//g;"` in a string variable.

Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raw Strings in Java - for regex in particular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256667/raw-strings-in-java-for-regex-in-particular)

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `\` by `\\` in a Java String literal.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html (at the bottom).

That is

```
String regExp = "~ s/\\n|\s+|.*?=|;//g;";
```

should work.