# Match everything except for specified strings

Tags: regex

I know that the following regex will match "red", "green", or "blue".

```
red|green|blue
```

Is there a straightforward way of making it match everything **except** several specified strings?

Comment: Not all flavours of regular expressions can do this. What environment are you working in? Java? Perl? .NET? Some C/C++ regex library? An RDBMS?

Comment: You don't say what you want it for, but you could simply invert the sense of the "match" operation.  This won't help you if you are trying do extraction on the non-matching parts, but to test whether an excluded string is not present it would work: `if (!s.match(/red|green|blue/)) ...`  Note: I know that the OP doesn't specify what language/framework, so the preceding should be considered a generic example, not a prescriptive one.

Answer (score 261):

If you want to make sure that the string is neither red, green nor blue, [caskey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404025/12268505) is it.  What is often wanted, however, is to make sure that the line does not contain red, green or blue anywhere in it.  For that, anchor the regular expression with `^` and include `.*` in the negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(red|green|blue))
```

Also, suppose that you want lines containing the word "engine" but without any of those colors:

```
^(?!.*(red|green|blue)).*engine
```

You might think you can factor the `.*` to the head of the regular expression:

```
^.*(?!red|green|blue)engine     # Does not work
```

but you cannot.  You have to have both instances of `.*` for it to work.

Comment: It is important to say that the lookahead is not part of either BRE (basic) or ERE (extended) regular expressions. You need PCRE (Perl compatible) or similar. ------ Your last example does not work because the greedy `.*` at the beginning will match anything. You need to have the initial match more specific. For example match just whitespace: `printf 'redengine\nblackengine\ngreenengine\n' | grep -P '^\s*(?!red|green|blue)\w*engine'`

Answer (score 85):

Depends on the language, but there are generally negative-assertions you can put in like so:

```
(?!red|green|blue)
```

(Thanks for the syntax fix, the above is valid Java and Perl, YMMV)

Comment: @caskey, The full answer is a combination of mine and yours.  If you'd like to merge them together, I'll delete mine.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful is you explained it a little. For example: What do "?" and "!" mean? Why do you need capture groups?

Comment: It's valid Python, too.

Comment: just used this with Delphi regEx library and it only works like this : ^(?!red|green|blue). Also true for testing it on https://regex101.com/ . So is the above a typo missing a ^ or does it actually work like that in Java/Perl/Python .. ?

Comment: I am curious about the answer on comment of @Lii

Comment: @Lii, this is a type of lookaround expression which is one that does not change the current overall evaluation position of the regex after it completes. This one is a Negative Lookahead, written as `(?!` which says, "from the current position in my regex, is the text that follows NOT 'red' or 'green' or blue'?" There are also positive look aheads, and positive & negative look _behinds_ where evaluation looks backwards from the current position. The key word is that it "looks" but doesn't "move".

Answer (score 69):

## Matching Anything but Given Strings

If you want to match the entire string where you want to match everything but certain strings you can do it like this:

`^(?!(red|green|blue)$).*$`

This says, start the match from the beginning of the string where it cannot start and end with red, green, or blue and match anything else to the end of the string.

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/2

Note that this only works with regex engines that support a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer, as it won't match words _containing_ the specific strings.

Answer (score 43):

You don't need negative lookahead. There is working example:

```
/([\s\S]*?)(red|green|blue|)/g
```

Description:

- `[\s\S]` - match any character
- `*` - match from 0 to unlimited from previous group
- `?` - match as less as possible
- `(red|green|blue|)` - match one of this words or nothing
- `g` - repeat pattern

Example:

`whiteredwhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredgreenbluewhiteredwhiteredwhiteredwhiteredwhiteredwhiteredgreenbluewhiteredwhiteredwhiteredwhiteredwhiteredredgreenredgreenredgreenredgreenredgreenbluewhiteredbluewhiteredbluewhiteredbluewhiteredbluewhiteredwhite`

Will be:

`whitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhitewhite`

Test it: [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/r/qS7bQ5/205)

Comment: You can drastically reduce the step count by swapping [\s\S] for a dot. I was very confused why seemingly every other example captures each word individually. This way is slightly more regex steps but requires far less post-processing.

Comment: but this doesn't do matching (text validation), it just removes specified text during substitution.

Comment: This solution will not output the final chunk of text after the known words. So, there is no need comparing the speed, it is just wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fixed.

Comment: This question is how to translate the regular language complement operator to something practical like PCRE. This answer is about a specific pattern of capture groups, not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same question, the solutions proposed were almost working but they had some issue. In the end the regex I used is:

```
^(?!red|green|blue).*
```

I tested it in Javascript and .NET.

`.*` should't be placed inside the negative lookahead like this: `^(?!.*red|green|blue)` or it would make the first element behave different from the rest (i.e. "anotherred" wouldn't be matched while "anothergreen" would)

Comment: The `^(?!.*red|green|blue)` would match everythin that begings differently that `.*red`, or that `green` or that `blue`.  The "anotherred" matches `.*red` at the begining so it is excluded. "anothergreen" does not match `green` at the begining, so it is atmitted. `^(?!.*(red|green|blue))` would work to exclude both "anotherred" and "anothergreen".

Answer (score 12):

Matching any text but those matching a pattern is usually achieved with ***splitting* the string with the regex pattern**.

*Examples*:

- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) - `Regex.Split(text, @"red|green|blue")` or, to get rid of empty values, `Regex.Split(text, @"red|green|blue").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/9DlMgp))
- [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) - `Regex.Split(text, "red|green|blue")` or, to remove empty items, `Regex.Split(text, "red|green|blue").Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/1k82T9), or [this demo](https://tio.run/##jdBBa8MgFAfwc/wUj5wUOmHsOHYYXQctXTeWQs4meySC0eDTkUG/e6aul916UZS/v/d8391d7zyu636anQ8EzQ8FnNj/ozzjEuQnDtEov1tmj0TaWWLsI3ZG97A1igjOSIFV16tmVB6/oIkdvCltuWBV9aInCImC5yQHr@0AT1Dn2D0MHtHCA3QmYp2y2@Q7g7L1OuBRW@R/L@TBJa1@rDeQGsJFNrPRgWd2U6xLkS7FEULcRqUU3OLJdkSP/DXaPqQJcBJwcuH6GbmnUzTm3bdjKkSz6jEFcgd52dkyDZb3Mq91/QU) where LINQ is supported)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - `text.split(/red|green|blue/)` (no need to use `g` modifier here!) (to get rid of empty values, use `text.split(/red|green|blue/).filter(Boolean)`), see [demo](https://tio.run/##jcsxDoAgDADA3Vc0TjgIMS4uLv4EsRJMAwaqcfDviL7A/W7Tp04mup3bc8iZ8eKxjrhABzYieuhhpgPrygSfAqGkYAW8TKadHAtV8P3R@4Wqgea/lasjxiimULj25eb8AA)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `text.split("red|green|blue")`, or - to keep all trailing empty items - use `text.split("red|green|blue", -1)`, or to remove all empty items use [more code to remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520693) (see [demo](https://ideone.com/O9Gs3X))
- [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) - Similar to Java, `text.split(/red|green|blue/)`, to get all trailing items use `text.split(/red|green|blue/, -1)` and to remove all empty items use `text.split(/red|green|blue/).findAll {it != ""})` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/UmZ03g))
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) - `text.split(Regex("red|green|blue"))` or, to remove blank items, use `text.split(Regex("red|green|blue")).filter{ !it.isBlank() }`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/pTlHgl)
- [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) - `text.split("red|green|blue")`, or to keep all trailing empty items, use `text.split("red|green|blue", -1)` and to remove all empty items, use `text.split("red|green|blue").filter(_.nonEmpty)` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/6KdDKw))
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) - `text.split(/red|green|blue/)`, to get rid of empty values use `.split(/red|green|blue/).reject(&:empty?)` (and to get both leading and trailing empty items, use `-1` as the second argument, `.split(/red|green|blue/, -1)`) (see [demo](https://ideone.com/fqavnQ))
- [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) - `my @result1 = split /red|green|blue/, $text;`, or with all trailing empty items, `my @result2 = split /red|green|blue/, $text, -1;`, or without any empty items, `my @result3 = grep { /\S/ } split /red|green|blue/, $text;` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/du5K5L))
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) - `preg_split('~red|green|blue~', $text)` or `preg_split('~red|green|blue~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` to output no empty items (see [demo](https://ideone.com/jDZ62X))
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `re.split(r'red|green|blue', text)` or, to remove empty items, `list(filter(None, re.split(r'red|green|blue', text)))` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/fjx0CI))
- [go](/questions/tagged/go) - Use `regexp.MustCompile("red|green|blue").Split(text, -1)`, and if you need to remove empty items, use [this code](https://dabase.com/e/15006/). See [Go demo](https://ideone.com/XXSkSH).

**NOTE**: If you patterns contain [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), regex split functions/methods [may](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) behave differently, also depending on additional options. Please refer to the appropriate split method documentation then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it case unsensitive use with ignore case flag i for ignore case.

Try this: `/^(?!(red|green|blue)$).+$/i` that works in most regex engine:

**JavaScript:**

```
const pattern = /^(?!(red|green|blue)$).+$/i
```

**Python:**

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(?!(red|green|blue)$).+$", re.IGNORECASE)
```

**PHP:**

```
$pattern = '/^(?!(red|green|blue)$).+$/i'
```

[Regex DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/1b85a4a4c05a).

Answer (score -1):

### All except word "red"

```js
var href = '(text-1) (red) (text-3) (text-4) (text-5)';

var test = href.replace(/\((\b(?!red\b)[\s\S]*?)\)/g, testF); 

function testF(match, p1, p2, offset, str_full) {
  p1 = "-"+p1+"-";
  return p1;
}

console.log(test);
```

### All except word "red"

```js
var href = '(text-1) (frede) (text-3) (text-4) (text-5)';

var test = href.replace(/\(([\s\S]*?)\)/g, testF); 

function testF(match, p1, p2, offset, str_full) {
  p1 = p1.replace(/red/g, '');
  p1 = "-"+p1+"-";
  return p1;
}

console.log(test);
```