# In Java, remove empty elements from a list of Strings

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, I have an ArrayList of Strings like:

```
[,Hi, ,How,are,you]
```

I want to remove the null and empty elements, how to change it so it is like this:

```
[Hi,How,are,you]
```

Answer (score 104):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", "Hi", null, "How"));
System.out.println(list);
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[, Hi, null, How]
[Hi, How]
```

Comment: Gives me `UnsupportedOperationException` from `java.util.AbstractList.remove()`...

Comment: Damn I've re-done it and it works. My bad. Sincerely.

Comment: Do we need to import from the `util` or `awt` library?

Comment: Is there a way to convert the list back to an array? And can we keep the same number of positions in the array as before? It would just move all the empty spaces to the end?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal they say Google is your friend - https://www.google.com/search?q=arraylist+to+array

Comment: it gives UnsupportedOperationException, not sure how it is working for others?

Answer (score 50):

Its a very late answer, but you can also use the `Collections.singleton`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", "Hi", null, "How"));
// in one line
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null))

// separately
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
```

Comment: it gives UnsupportedOperationException, not sure how it is working for others

Comment: @Derick If you don't wrap the Arrays.asList with new ArrayList<String>, then it would give UnsupportedOperationException. Because Arrays.asList cannot be structurally modified, so removeIf operation cannot be done.

Answer (score 30):

Another way to do this now that we have Java 8 lambda expressions.

```
arrayList.removeIf(item -> item == null || "".equals(item));
```

Comment: With Guava you can do `arrayList.removeIf(Strings::isNullOrEmpty);`.

Comment: Or with Apache Commons `arrayList.removeIf(StringUtils::isEmpty);`

Comment: Or if you want to remove entries that are nothing but whitespace characters as well `arrayList.removeIf(StringUtils::isBlank);`

Comment: By the way, there's no point in using yoda comparison once you're checking for null.

Comment: Java 11: `arrayList.removeIf(String::isBlank);`

Answer (score 9):

1. If you were asking *how* to remove the empty strings, you can do it like this (where `l` is an `ArrayList<String>`) - this removes all `null` references and strings of length 0:

   ```
   Iterator<String> i = l.iterator();
   while (i.hasNext())
   {
       String s = i.next();
       if (s == null || s.isEmpty())
       {
           i.remove();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Don't confuse an `ArrayList` with arrays, an `ArrayList` is a dynamic data-structure that resizes according to it's contents. If you use the code above, you don't have to do anything to get the result as you've described it -if your `ArrayList` was ["","Hi","","How","are","you"], after removing as above, it's going to be exactly what you need - `["Hi","How","are","you"]`.

   However, if you *must* have a 'sanitized' **copy** of the original list (while leaving the original as it is) and by '*store it back*' you meant '*make a copy*', then krmby's code in the other answer will serve you just fine.

Comment: there is **no zero-arg magical remove method** on arratlist as you mentioned.

Comment: Please take a closer look - the `remove()` is invoked on an [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) not on an `ArrayList`

Comment: from ypur answer **if you've called remove() on the ArrayList**

Comment: What you can do is call remove("") if you just want to remove all empty strings.  That won't work for strings with just whitespace though.

Comment: @krmby Edited it, thanks. @squaknull Neat, didn't think of that (although you'll still have to do it in a loop). And it depends on what the OP means by 'empty' - I've put in a disclaimer indicating that this loop will remove all `null` and empty strings only.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java 8 then try this using lambda expression and [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)), that will also clear `null` and `blank` values from `array` input

```
public static String[] cleanArray(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> !StringUtils.isBlank(x)).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935895/9696526

Comment: Lambda in filter can be replaced with method reference too:
```filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)```

Answer (score 7):

Going to drop this lil nugget in here:

```
Stream.of("", "Hi", null, "How", "are", "you")
  .filter(t -> !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(t))
  .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

I wish with all of my heart that Java had a `filterNot`.

Comment: What's Strings - is that Guava?

Comment: @JWoodchuck Yeah I believe so.

Comment: Been a while since I answered this, but looks like it's Guava.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few approaches that you could use:

1. Iterate over the list, calling `Iterator.remove()` for the list elements you want to remove.  This is the simplest.
2. Repeatedly call `List.remove(Object)`.  This is simple too, but performs worst of all ... because you repeatedly scan the *entire list*.  (However, this might be an option for a mutable list whose iterator didn't support `remove` ... for some reason.)
3. Create a new list, iterate over the old list, adding elements that you want to retain to a new list.
4. If you can't return the new list, as 3. above and then clear the old list and use `addAll` to add the elements of the new list back to it.

Which of these is fastest depends on the class of the original list, its size, and the number of elements that need to be removed.  Here are some of the factors:

- For an `ArrayList`, each individual `remove` operation is `O(N)`, where `N` is the list size.  It is expensive to remove multiple elements from a large ArrayList using the `Iterator.remove()` method (or the `ArrayList.remove(element)` method).

  By contrast, the `Iterator.remove` method for a `LinkedList` is `O(1)`.
- For an `ArrayList`, creating and copying a list is `O(N)` and  *relatively* cheap, especially if you can ensure that the destination list's capacity is large enough (but not too large).

  By contrast, creating and copying to a `LinkedList` is also `O(N)`, but considerably more expensive.

All of this adds up to a fairly complicated decision tree.  If the lists are small (say 10 or less elements) you can probably get away with any of the approaches above.  If the lists could be large, you need to weigh up all of the issues in the list of the expected list size and expected number of removals.  (Otherwise you might end up with quadratic performance.)

Answer (score 4):

- This code compiles and runs smoothly.
- It uses no iterator so more readable.
- list is your collection.
- result is filtered form (no null no empty).

---

```
public static void listRemove() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("", "Hi", "", "How", "are", "you");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String str : list) {
        if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(str);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: This can throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException` since `str` could be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

If you get `UnsupportedOperationException` from using one of ther answer above and your `List` is created from `Arrays.asList()`, it is because you can't edit such `List`.

To fix, wrap the `Arrays.asList()` inside `new LinkedList<String>()`:

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(split));
```

Source is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2965808).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the comment of Andrew Mairose - Although a fine solution, I would just like to add that this solution will not work on **fixed size** lists.

You could attempt doing like so:

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", null, "c", "    "})
    .removeIf(item -> item == null || "".equals(item));
```

But you'll encounter an `UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.remove`(since `asList` returns a non-resizable List).

A different solution might be this:

```
List<String> collect =
    Stream.of(new String[]{"a", "b", "c", null, ""})
        .filter(item -> item != null && !"".equals(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which will produce a nice list of strings :-)

Comment: Good point, but the OP did say it was an `ArrayList`, which is not fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

lukastymo's answer seems the best one.

But it may be worth mentioning this approach as well for it's extensibility:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", "Hi", null, "How"));

list = list.stream()
           .filter(item -> item != null && !item.isEmpty())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

What I mean by that (extensibility) is you could then add additional filters, such as:

```
          .filter(item -> !item.startsWith("a"))
```

... although of course that's not specifically relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("", "Hi", "", "How"));
           Stream<String> stream = list .stream();
           Predicate<String> empty = empt->(empt.equals(""));
            Predicate<String> emptyRev = empty.negate();
           list=  stream.filter(emptyRev).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

OR

```
list =  list .stream().filter(empty->(!empty.equals(""))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private List cleanInputs(String[] inputArray) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(inputArray.length);
        for (String input : inputArray) {
            if (input != null) {
                String str = input.trim();
                if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                    result.add(str);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// Here i have posted two approaches, please go through it

```
private static void consumerExample() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Java", "\n \n", "Python", " ", null);
    System.out.println("==================== ");
    Consumer<List<String>> modify = list1 -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)
            if (getOnlyStrings(list1.get(i)).length() > 0)
                System.out.println(list1.get(i));
    };
    modify.accept(list);
    System.out.println("====================");
}

public static String getOnlyStrings(String s) {
    String str = "";
    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z]");
        if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0)
            return "";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        str = matcher.replaceAll("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    consumerExample();
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Java", "\n \n", "Python", " ", null);

    List<String> collection = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", null, "B", null, "C", "", "D"));

    // collection.removeIf(s -> s == null || "".equals(s));

    // System.out.println(collection);

    list.stream().filter(p -> getOnlyStrings(p).length() > 0).forEach(System.out::println);
    ;
}
```