# Replace part of string that doesn't match regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am attempting to replace parts of a string that **don't** match a regular expression pattern using JavaScript. This is functionally equivalent to using the `-v` flag in a GNU grep to invert results. Here is an example:

```
// I want to replace all characters that don't match "fore" 
// in "aforementioned" with "*"

'aforementioned'.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'i'), function(match){
    //generates a string of '*' that is the length of match
    return new Array(match.length).join('*');
});
```

I am looking for a regex for `pattern`. This would be something like the opposite of `(fore)`. I've searched around but haven't been able to implement any related question's answers to fit my needs. Here is a list anyway, maybe it will point us in the right direction:

- [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)
- [Match everything except for specified strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should be one possible solution:

```
'aforementioned'.replace(new RegExp(pattern + '|.', 'gi'), function(c) {
    return c === pattern ? c : '*';
});

>> "*fore*********"
```

Comment: what is the pattern that you used?