# Replace all chars that not match regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace (javascript) all chars that not in regex pattern with '_' 
 Example

string: `#he57/h`

Pattern: `/^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`

Expected result: `_he57_h`

I tried

```js
var str = "#he57/h";
var res = str.replace(/^[^_a-zA-Z][^_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g, "_");
console.log(res);
```

But its not do the work.

Comment: Well, @AlexK was right, you really need to replace each non-word char with `_` in this case. Use `str.replace(/\W/g, '_')`. At least it seems so. Else, use https://jsfiddle.net/5fox81bw/ that is a generic solution.

Comment: if looking for a general solution, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118657/replace-part-of-string-that-doesnt-match-regex

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. Can you please add some explanation on your solution and why my example didnt work?

Comment: Your second character is an alpha character. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` would find any non alphanumerical character. See https://regex101.com/r/fcqDzk/1/ for longer explanation.