# match all file name with specific extension except for specific file-name regex

Tags: java, regex

From the following list

```
"foo.exe"
"foo.dmg"
"baz.exe"
"this-is-another-file-name.exe"
...
```

what java regex would match every strings that end with `".exe"` except a specific string `"baz.exe"`

Thanks!

EDIT:  I've tried  `(?=\.exe$)(?!baz\.exe)`

**UPDATE** by [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4807875/alexander-samoylov). There are two solutions:

1. `(?<!^baz)\.exe` - using negative lookbehind, the matching group is only .exe part of the word
2. `^(?!baz\.exe).*` - using negative lookahead, the matching group contain the whole file name

Both work with "grep -P" and from Java (`\\` must be replace with `\`).
Be aware also that Java's Matcher.*matches*() and Matcher.*find*() work differently, see my example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegexLookaround {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] strings = new String[] { "bax.exe", "baz.exe", "baza.exe", "abaz.exe", "bazbaz.exe" };
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        for (String s : strings) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println("m: " + m.group());  
            }
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("f: " + m.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
$ java -cp . RegexLookaround '(?<!^baz)\.exe'
f: .exe
f: .exe
f: .exe
f: .exe

$ java -cp . RegexLookaround '^(?!baz\.exe).*'
m: bax.exe
m: baza.exe
m: abaz.exe
m: bazbaz.exe
```

Comment: If you have tried anything please post it.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The correct solution is `(?<!^baz)\.exe` or `^(?!baz\.exe).*`.

I don't agree with the duplicate mark, because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern has just general formulations and no solution for this particular task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would `look behind` for presence of `baz` and **discard** the match if it's present.
I assume that you are checking `filenames` one by one. Hence used anchor `^` and `$`.

**Regex:** `^(?!baz).*\.exe$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN8fP4/1)**

Comment: I am sorry, @user2705585, but your proposal does not work for baza.exe, abaz.exe.
Also I think ?! is lookahead, the lookbehind is ?<!. As I see from http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html: 1) "... to match a q not followed by a u. Negative lookahead provides the solution: q(?!u).", 2) "(?<!a)b matches a “b” that is not preceded by an “a”, using negative *lookbehind*".

Answer (score 1):

As @Wajahat noted, this question can be answered straight from [Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings) (first google answer too).

`^(?!.*(baz)).*exe`

- foo.exe : matches
- baz.exe : does not match
- whaterver.exe : matches

Comment: It does not find indeed *whatever*.exe. It works only if *whatever* does not contain "baz", that is for baza.exe, abaz.exe it won't work.