# gsub with exception in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm removing English characters from Hebrew text but would like to keep a short list of English words that i want, e.g. `words2keep <- c("ok", "hello", "yes*")`.
So my current regex is `text <- gsub("[A-Z,a-z]", "", text)` , but the question is how to add the exception so it will not remove all English words.

reproducibe example:

```
text = "ok אני מסכים איתך Yossi Cohen"
```

after gsub with exception

```
text = "ok אני מסכים איתך"
```

Thank you for all suggestions

Comment: This pose seems like it might have your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one. I think we can do it by matching against whole words by making use of the `\b` word boundary assertion, and at the same time include a negative lookahead assertion just prior to the match which rejects the words (again, *whole words*) that you want to blacklist for removal (or equivalently whitelist for preservation). This appears to be working:

```
gsub(perl=T,paste0('(?!\\b',paste(collapse='\\b|\\b',words2keep),'\\b)\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b'),'',text);
[1] "ok אני מסכים איתך  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub function with [A-Z] All uppercase A to Z letters will be removed, for total word removal use .* for total character removal

```
gsub("[A-Z].*","",text)

[1] "ok אני מסכים איתך "

#data

text = "ok אני מסכים איתך Yossi Cohen"
```

Comment: This is just working by chance and has nothing to do with the question