# Replace duplicate letters with exception

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I'm trying to replace any duplicated letter with a one letter.
I use `gsub` here and it's working:

```
text <- c("This tree is veeeeery tall")
gsub("([a-zA-Z])\\1+", "\\1", text)
##[1] "This tre is very tal"
```

**BUT** I need to make exception for some words to be like this:

```
"This tree is very tall"
```

I tried the solution in this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061395/gsub-with-exception-in-r) but it doesn't work.

```
text <- c("This tree is veeeeery tall")
words2keep <- c("tree", "tall")
gsub(perl=T,paste0('(?!\\b',paste(collapse='\\b|\\b',words2keep),'\\b)\\b([a-zA-Z])\\1+\\b'),'\\1',text)
##[1] "This tree is veeeeery tall"
```

So, is there any way to do it?

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. Show the code you actually tried and say exactly what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @MrFlick I edited can you check it now

Comment: It is quite easy with a PCRE regex. All you need is to match the exception words  and skip them with [`\b(?:tree|tall)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-zA-Z])\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/1HDyq1/1) regex. See the [**R demo**](https://ideone.com/jRX9mM).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is awesome! First time learning this method of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Please make this an answer.

Comment: I see it was re-opened, I "converted" (not "moved") my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a PCRE `perl=TRUE` option, it is easy to introduce exceptions to a regex. All you need is an alternation operator that will delimit two main parts: the first, left, part is what we match and skip, and the second is what we want to actually process.

```
\b(?:tree|tall)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-zA-Z])\1+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1HDyq1/1)

**Details**

- `\b(?:tree|tall)\b(*SKIP)(*F)` - a leading word boundary, a whole word `tree` or `tall`, a trailing word boundary, and the combination of the 2 PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` that make the regex engine skip the match and proceed looking for the next one from the current position (end of the skipped match)
- `|` - or
- `([a-zA-Z])\1+` - any ASCII letter captured into Group 1 and then one or more repetitions of the same letter (note that `\p{L}` with `(*UCP)` verb makes the pattern fully Unicode-aware)

To build the regex dynamically in R, you need to `paste` the exception word vector into the left part of the regex:

```
text <- c("This tree is veeeeery tall")
words2keep <- c("tree", "tall")
p <- paste0('\\b(?:',paste(collapse='|',words2keep),')\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z])\\1+')
## OR: p <- paste0('(*UCP)\\b(?:',paste(collapse='|',words2keep),')\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\p{L})\\1+')
p
## => [1] "\\b(?:tree|tall)\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z])\\1+"
gsub(p, '\\1',text, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "This tree is very tall"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/jRX9mM)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `str_replace_all` from `stringr`:

```
text1 <- c("This tree is veeeeery tall")
text2 <- c("This tree is vaeeeeery tall")
text3 <- c("This tree is eeeeery tall")
words2keep <- c("tree", "tall")

library(stringr)
replace_func = function(string){
  str_replace_all(string, "(\\w)\\1+", "\\1")
}

names(words2keep) = replace_func(words2keep)


text_clean1 = replace_func(text1)
str_replace_all(text_clean1, words2keep)
# [1] "This tree is very tall"

text_clean2 = replace_func(text2)
str_replace_all(text_clean2, words2keep)
# [1] "This tree is vaery tall"

text_clean3 = replace_func(text3)
str_replace_all(text_clean3, words2keep)
# [1] "This tree is ery tall"
```

This solution first runs `words2keep` through the same `str_replace_all` that `text` is going to go through and make the result the names of `words2keep`:

```
> words2keep
   tre    tal 
"tree" "tall"
```

The same `str_replace_all` is then applied to `text` to remove all repeating word characters:

```
> replace_func(text1)
[1] "This tre is very tal"
```

Finally, the trick is to have a third `str_replace_all` that replaces the incorrectly modified words with the original words by supplying the *named* `words2keep` vector.