# How to use gsub to remove character from string, with exceptions

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am deleting all line break dashes followed by a space('- ') from a character string in R, expect from those preceded by 'en' (has something to do with Dutch grammar). Using this example ([gsub with exception in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061395/gsub-with-exception-in-r))
 I got close to an answer, but just cannot figure it out completely.

This is an example of a string

```r
string <- "word1 long- er word2, word3 en- word4"
```

expected result:

```r
"word1 longer word2, word3 en- word4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option can be negative regex lookaround to match a `-` followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`) not (`!`) preceded by the character 'en'

```
gsub("(?<!en)(-\\s+)", "", string, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "word1 longer word2, word3 en- word4"
```

---

Or with `SKIP/FAIL` to make the matched pattern fail when the pattern is preceded by 'en'

```
gsub("(en-\\s+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|-\\s+", "", string, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "word1 longer word2, word3 en- word4"
```

Comment: @LSmeets. I think both should work work for similar patterns.  There couldd be edge cases.  If this has to be limited to only words and not substrings place a `\\b` before the `en`