# Regex match all except a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help. I already tried to practice in several ways, but it didn't work as expected. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings/2404330#).

I want to match all single words except the pattern `<br>` in JS.

So I tried

```
(?!<br>)[\s\S]
(?!<|b|r|>)[\s\S]
```

The problem I have is, in the `?!` quote, it's matching either the first word, `<` only, not the entire pattern `<br>`. In reverse, just `<br>` can match all `<br>` expect any other words. How can I let it know I want to match the entire word in the `?!` quote?

Thank you so much!

[Here is what I am trying](https://regex101.com/r/vEVgtM/1/).

Comment: Remove the [`?!`](https://regex101.com/r/vEVgtM/2)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I want to exclude < br >

Comment: What about `str = str.replace(/<br>/g, '');` ?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I want a excluding match not replacement...I already know that.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @RobG not matching <br>

Comment: Can you please provide a sample string and your expected output.

Comment: @RobG can you fix my example? https://regex101.com/r/vEVgtM/1/

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Can you help to fix my example? to exclude all <br>. https://regex101.com/r/vEVgtM/1/

Comment: @Till, you are doing it all wrong. Do not try to do everything with 1 regex, it is not that powerful in JS as in PCRE. You cannot skip any match, but in your code, you can. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z9coueyL/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So you are saying that there is no such excluding match in JS?

Comment: No way to skip a match with JS regex. But you may match and capture what you need, and  just match what you do not need, see [this JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z9coueyL/). Is that the required output, `[" ", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "r", "<", "p", ">"]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you already gave me what I want. The result its excluding <br>, I need to spend time to learn how this work. Ty so much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, sorry, its not...its pushing to an array.

Comment: @Till: instead of turning mad all the people that read your question, explain what you want to do and what is the final goal of this. You will get better answers.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Or existing answers may get improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you are looking for might look like this:

```
([^>]|<(?!br>)[^>]+>)+(?=<br>|$)
```

It should work for any tag, try replacing `br` by `p` in the above pattern.

[<sup>Regex101 link</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/vEVgtM/6/)

**However**, It would be much *easier* and *readable* and *faster* to use:

```
content.split('<br>').filter(x => x.length)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I suggested splitting in the very first comment, but OP did not provide any feedback, and I removed it after some 10th comment. Perhaps, there is something else  OP is doing "behind the scenes".