# Remove any lower case character except specific combinations

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this string: `azjf8ee7Ldoge \n Hmeqze= AZ12D Fs \nsdfz14eZe148r`.
I want to match all lower case characters except when it is an **e followed by a digit** (`e\d`) or when it is a **backslash followed by n** (`\\n`).
Based on the answers I found here:
[How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)
[Match everything except for specified strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings)
I managed to find a solution: `(?!(e\d|\\n))[a-z]` which works well, except that it matches the `n` that comes after a backslash.
[Link for a demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/258)
How to exclude matching an `n` preceded by a backslash?

Comment: `re.findall(r'e\d|\\n|([a-z])', text)`? Or are you replacing? Like `re.sub(r'(e\d|\\n)|[a-z]', r'\1', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU68PW/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I am replacing in fact..

Comment: Like `re.sub(r'(e\d|\\n)|[a-z]', r'\1', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU68PW/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you, that works. Please post it as an answer :-)

Comment: Sorry, I added another lookaround based solution following my logic to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To keep any `e` with a single digit after and `\n` two-char sequences, and remove any lowercase ASCII letter in other contexts** you may use

```
re.sub(r'(e\d|\\n)|[a-z]', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU68PW/1)

**Details**

- `(e\d|\\n)` - matches and captures into Group 1 (referred to with `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern) an `e` and a single digit or a `\` and an `n` char
- `|` - or
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter.

The `\1` restores the captured values in the result.

If you want to play with lookarounds you may use

```
[a-z](?<!e(?=\d))(?<!\\n)
re.sub(r'[a-z](?<!e(?=\d))(?<!\\n)', '', text)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU68PW/3)

The `[a-z](?<!e(?=\d))(?<!\\n)` pattern matches any ASCII lowercase letter (`[a-z]`) that is not `e` followed with a digit (`(?<!e(?=\d))`) and is not `n` preceded with `n` (`(?<!\\n)`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid matching `\n` then you may add a negative lookahead assertion in your regex:

```
(?!e\d|\\n)[a-z](?<!\\n)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/262)

`(?<!\\n)` is negative lookbehind assertion that ensures that we don't have `\n` at previous position after matching `[a-z]` within your match.

Comment: I think the right answer should be: `(?!(e\d|\\n))[a-z](?<!\\n)` because the answer you proposed still matches **e followed by a digit**

Comment: Oh yes, `(?!e\d|\\n)[a-z](?<!\\n)` would be the right one

Answer (score 1):

You could match char a-z and make use of lookarounds:

```
(?!e\d)[a-z](?<!\\[a-z])
```

In parts

- `(?!e\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `e` followed by a digit
- `[a-z]` Match a char a-z
- `(?<!\\[a-z])` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `\` followed by a char a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/occvWQ/1/)