# REGEX find all but float before € sign

Tags: regex

My test string is:

```
let str = 'fooo 34.52€ bar <span>10x</span>'
```

I need to get all of the string but the float that is before the € sign.
I managed to get only the float with:

```
[\d\.]+(?=€)
```

But i would like to get all except this.

Comment: Split with the pattern to get all but the number.

Comment: And how do you do that. I need it to work for any float. My understanding of regex is insufficient to get my answer from what you assigned as the duplicate post.

Comment: I linked to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311100/3832970)