# Regex to find text between a pair of words if the first word does not appear again

Tags: regex

I need to capture the string `||EPB||` and `|TRN|` but only if they appear as a pair.

My text looks like this.

`||EPB|| 1-2-3 |TRN| ||EPB||....||EPB|| Other text ||EPB|| 11-2-3 Test A |TRN| more text that may have carriage returns in it ||EPB||nospace/here||EPB|| 12-2-3 |TRN|`

I want the results to be:

- 1-2-3
- 11-2-3 Test A
- 12-2-3

The closest I got was
`\|\|EPB\|\|(.*?)\|TRN\|`
But that doesn't handle the situation where there is more than one ||EPB|| appears before a |TRN|

Comment: Use `\|\|EPB\|\|((?:(?!\|\|EPB\|\|).)*?)\|TRN\|`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/apXx8P/1

Comment: Duplicate of: [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern), [Match everything except for specified strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2404010/8967612)

Comment: `(?<=[|]{2}EPB[|]{2})\s*([^|]*?)\s*(?=[|]TRN[|])` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/00YSLQ/1)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was unnecessarily complex when compared to that proposed by @41686d6564 in a comment above. I have therefore deleted it.

Comment: @Daniel, your regex does not match  `"1-2-|3"` in `"||EPB|| 1-2-|3 |TRN|"`.

Comment: @41686d6564, nice one. You could of course avoid the capture group with [lookarounds](https://regex101.com/r/TkelBm/1).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, that was intentional.  If pipes are the delimiter here then the only `|` that should match is one that is complete as `|TRN|`

Answer (score -1):

My solution though not perfect is better than the closest you got above.

**(?<=||EPB||)(.*?)(?=|TRN|)**

It attempts to "wrap" your string between a positive look behind assertion (match ||EPB|| but nothing before it) and a positive look ahead assertion(match |TRN| but nothing after it).

For a regular expression cheat sheet:
https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: edited again to be more explanatory.