# REGEX to find match with any whitespace plus a special character plus a single whitespace plus anything with exceptions:

Tags: regex

#### Intro:

I am looking to make a code hinter in Javascript for Vue i18n localizations.

#### Details:

Using Node readline to read line by line through a Vue file I want to find one pattern using REGEX (of the many patterns I am looking for) which story-wise is as follows:

> For a single string,
>
> find any amount of whitespace (spaces or indents)
>
> PLUS
>
> exactly one closing parenthesis
>
> PLUS
>
> exactly one space (for now, this might change)
>
> PLUS (tricky part, bare with me)
>
> any amount of characters, numbers, or special characters  except {{$t('[anything here]'}} or {{ $t('[anything here]' }} or if there is nothing after the closing parenthesis altogether this line would fail to match the pattern.

```
1 |     )
2 |                     )
3 |  ) {
4 |      ) {{
5 |          ) Cancel
6 |        ) .[];\`\'.;l][
7 |             ) {{ $t('common.cancel') }}
8 |           ) {{$t('common.cancel')}}
```

Lines 1-2 and lines 7-8 should not match. Only lines 3-6 should match.

#### Attempted Solution:

So far my REGEX pattern is this:
`\s+\)\s{1}(.*)` which does not match Lines 1 and 2 (good thing) because of the lack of a single whitespace after the closing parenthesis.

#### Problem:

It allows Lines 7 and 8 to pass. I can't figure out how to say anything is allowed BUT the three exception scenarios mentioned in the story of what I am trying to achieve.

#### My brain now:

Thinking baby steps, I want to negate a `{` after the single whitespace portion. If I try `\s+\)\s{1}(.*)[^\{]`, the not block would negate any of the lines with an opening curly bracket from passing the match. But that's not the case because I am assuming the `(.*)` portion renders the negate block useless. Can't seem to even make this baby step. Please help.

Comment: No, but I would love to help clarify this if you can help me out:
It could be `'common.cancel'` or it could be `'something.something.aThing'` or it could be `'foo.bar'`
Does that help clarify and if so could you help me rephrase this post to make that make sense? Or do I need to give you any more details? Trying to be a legit poster here and not make terrible question posts.

Comment: I hear you. [regex] QAs are a minefield, unfortunately. This, Not sure if I can follow completely. How about this? `^\s+\)\s(?!.*{{ ?\$t\('[^']*'\) ?}}).+$` https://regex101.com/r/PiWNt3/1

Comment: You are an absolute rockstar. This is amazing. Where did you learn this beast, regex? I'm realizing the power regex can provide to things like code styling, code review, and other handy dev tools. Was hoping you might have a clue on where I can get a more solid foundation with regex.

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote my answer to your question. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Following your requirements, I came up with this pattern:

```
^\s+\)\s(?!.*{{ ?\$t\('[^']*'\) ?}}).+$
```

It's using the common 'Everything but..' approach ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern))
with the extra bits added in the front and at the end.

[Online Test](http://%20regex101.com/r/PiWNt3/1)