# Python split() without removing the delimiter

Tags: python, split, delimiter

This code almost does what I need it to..

```
for line in all_lines:
    s = line.split('>')
```

Except it removes all the '>' delimiters.

So,

```
<html><head>
```

Turns into

```
['<html','<head']
```

Is there a way to use the split() method but *keep* the delimiter, instead of removing it?

With these results..

```
['<html>','<head>']
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but if you're trying to parse HTML in Python, I highly recommend [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: See also [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators).

Comment: This question should be reopened. The duplicate one is regex-specific.

Comment: @orestisf Also, the "duplicate" one answers a different problem. `['<html', '>', '<head', '>', '']` is different from `['<html>', '<head>']`.  I know it's been a few months but I just voted to reopen.  If you do too someone else make take it over the finish line?

Comment: re.split(r"(?<=>(?!$))", '<html><head>') directly gives the answer. This way it can be handled by playing with regex look-arounds

Comment: The question contains a clear error: `"<html><head>".split(">")` produces three strings, namely `['<html','<head', ""]`, *not* the list `['<html','<head']`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
d = ">"
for line in all_lines:
    s =  [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
```

Comment: That works perfectly... but I don't fully understand what's going on.

Comment: @some1 it basically iterates over the results of the split and adds the delimiter back in. "s is a list, where each element in that list is e + d, where e are the elements in the result of line.split(d), but only if e isn't empty"

Comment: This adds a delimiter to all elements of the resulting list, including a single-element list with no delimiter... What if you _only_ wanted the delimiter appended to the first of the split elements?

Comment: Very old post but for the record: `if e` is enough, `!=""` can be omitted.

Comment: this is sloppy.  what if the string is "a.b." or ".a.b." and split on "."

Comment: And what if youre using regex to split the string?

Comment: @kasheemlew what you mean if d wasn't ">" but [">", "<"]? So instead of a string int was a list of strings?

Comment: Fails with `"a..b"` as well

Comment: I've posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436083/3430986 that should cover all edge cases

Comment: This will add a delimiter at the end of the string even if it don't exist at the end in original string.

Answer (score 38):

If you are parsing HTML with splits, you are most likely doing it wrong, except if you are writing a one-shot script aimed at a fixed and secure content file. If it is supposed to work on any HTML input, how will you handle something like `<a title='growth > 8%' href='#something'>`?

Anyway, the following works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(<[^>]*>)', '<body><table><tr><td>')[1::2]
['<body>', '<table>', '<tr>', '<td>']
```

Comment: If you are not sure whether the string in question will end with the deliminator in question, looks like you can do:  `re.split("(.*\n?)", "my\nstr\ning")[1::2]`

Comment: If you want to be parsing html, should go to https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/ and read this chapter. Has everything you need to know about parsing html and webscraping. If this link ever breaks, look into using the requests, beautifulsoup, and selenium libraries.

Answer (score 23):

How about this:

```
import re
s = '<html><head>'
re.findall('[^>]+>', s)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just split it, then for each element in the array/list (apart from the last one) add a trailing ">" to it.

Comment: What about the case of ">>" it would just become ">"

Comment: @paulm no, because splitting two `>`s like in `"<html>>body".split('>')` creates an empty element in the middle `["<html", "", "body"]`. Unless you WANT multiple `>`s to result in just a single `>` after processing, in which case you could first remove those empty strings.