# Split string on ". ","! " or "? " keeping the punctuation mark

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter)

I wish to split a string as follows:

```
text = " T?e  qu!ck ' brown 1 fox!     jumps-.ver. the 'lazy' doG?  !"
result -> (" T?e  qu!ck ' brown 1 fox!", "jumps-.ver.", "the 'lazy' doG?", "!")
```

So basically I want to split at `". "`, `"! "` or `"? "` but I want the spaces at the split points to be removed but not the dot, comma or question-mark.

How can I do this in an efficient way?

The str split function takes only on separator. I wonder is the best solution to split on all spaces and then find those that end with dot, comma or question-mark when constructing the required result.

Comment: @Dominic Kexel The two question are certainly related but they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this using a regular expression split:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = " T?e  qu!ck ' brown 1 fox! jumps-.ver. the 'lazy' doG?  !"
>>> re.split('(?<=[.!?]) +',text)
[" T?e  qu!ck ' brown 1 fox!", 'jumps-.ver.', "the 'lazy' doG?", '!']
```

The regular expression `'(?<=[.!?]) +'` means match a sequence of one or more spaces (`' +'`) only if preceded by a ., ! or ? character (`'(?<=[.!?])'`).

Comment: Important to note that `re` is a built in python library!