# Python find text using regex for this pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to separate the text based on occurrence of `db access` in the following text,

```
db access alpha customer1
 deny bla bla
db access beta customer99
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
db access game customer14
 permit no
!
```

(Actual text start with `\r\n` on linux). I want

```
db access alpha customer1
 deny bla bla
```

and

```
db access beta customer99
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
 permit bla bla
```

and

```
db access game customer14
 permit no
```

as separate element. I closest I can get is,

```
>>> re.findall('db\s+access.*?db\s+access',txt,re.M|re.S)
['db access alpha customer1\n     deny bla bla\n    db access']
```

and

```
>>> re.findall('db\s+access.*?!',txt,re.M|re.S)
['db access alpha customer1\n     deny bla bla\n    db access beta customer99\n     permit bla bla\n     permit bla bla\n     permit bla bla\n     permit bla bla\n    db access game customer14\n     permit no\n    !']
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good use case for regex.

Comment: This looks like a good use case the `split` function.

Comment: txt.split('\r\ndb access ')

Comment: @AndersonGreen @RobertHarvey  Yes, Other option I have is to convert txt in list and then iterate over to find `db access` and create a separate txt

Comment: You can also split a string without removing its separators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make use of regex, then you could use a positive lookahead:

```
>>> txt = '''
... 
... db access alpha customer1
...  deny bla bla
... db access beta customer99
...  permit bla bla
...  permit bla bla
...  permit bla bla
...  permit bla bla
... db access game customer14
...  permit no
... !'''
>>> re.findall('db\s+access.*?(?=db\s+access|!)',s,re.M|re.S)
['db access alpha customer1\n deny bla bla\n', 'db access beta customer99\n permit bla bla\n permit bla bla\n permit bla bla\n permit bla bla\n', 'db access game customer14\n permit no\n']
```

Comment: it works like a charm. I didn't get `?=db\s+access`. Will you please explain this?

Comment: I saw the doc,https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html it explain very well thanks.

Comment: @Netro It'd match something followed by `db\s+access` or `!` without making those a part of the match.