# how to split sentences with multiple splitting parameters and including split elements

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I have a text suppose 
`'this is my a,b,c,and d.'`

I want a list corresponding to the text as

`['this',' ','is',' ',my,' ','a',',','b',',','c',' ','and',' ','d','.']` .

The present split() method eliminated element by which it is splitting and it does not support multiple splitting parameters.

I want list from a string spliced with respect to special characters including the special characters in the list. What is the simplest way to achieve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the consecutive word characters and the non-word characters. That should give you the following result.

```
data = 'this is my a,b,c,and d.'
import re
print re.findall(r"\w+|\W+", data)
# ['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'a', ',', 'b', ',', 'c', ',', 'and', ' ', 'd', '.']
```