# How to split HTML text ignoring spaces in tags

Tags: python, list, split

I have html text like so:

```
myHTML = 'I like <a class="thing1 thing2">this thing</a>'
myHTMLarray = myHTML.Split(' ')
>>>['I','like','<a','class="thing1','thing2">this','thing</a>']
```

I need to ignore the spaces in tags (anything between '<' and '>'). My desired result would be:

```
>>>['I','like','<a class="thing1 thing2">this','thing</a>']
```

Ideally, I would like to ensure that exactly one word from the text is in each element of the list. Thus break tags or span tags without text other than a space would get included with the previous word.

Comment: Perhaps I could do some sort of regex to get split() to ignore the spaces in tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter What about this ?

Comment: @Matzyschneider I actually don't want tags as different elements. I want them included with exactly one word from the text. I'm fine with <head></head><body><p>firstword all being in one element

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ may be it can help :) or here you can try out your regexp :P http://pythex.org/

Comment: I thought about doing something like soup.string.split(' '), but I wasn't sure how I would go about putting the html tags back into the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to ignore spaces inside tags. To do that, you need to keep track of beginning and closing tag angle brackets and to detect spaces occuring elsewhere, but not between the brackets.

Once we have only significant spaces, we can detect space/word and word/space boundaries and extract all words using slices.

```
def mysplit(html):
    in_tag = False
    in_word = False
    for i, ch in enumerate(html):
        if ch == '<':
            in_tag = True
        elif ch == '>':
            in_tag = False
        space = ch.isspace() and not in_tag
        if not in_word and not space:
            in_word = True
            begin = i
        elif in_word and space:
            in_word = False
            yield html[begin:i]
    if in_word:
        yield html[begin:]

testhtml = 'I like <a class="thing1 thing2">this thing</a>'
print(list(mysplit(testhtml)))
# prints: ['I', 'like', '<a class="thing1 thing2">this', 'thing</a>']
```

Edit: I made a small change to the code posted originally to increase readability a little bit.

Comment: I'm thinking this might solve all my problems... Looking to see if I can get this to split only when there has been at least one word of text in the element.