# split string without removal of delimiter in python

Tags: python, split

I need to split a string without removal of delimiter in Python.

Eg:

```
content = 'This 1 string is very big 2 i need to split it 3 into paragraph wise. 4 But this string 5 not a formated string.'
content = content.split('\s\d\s')
```

After this I am getting like this:

```
This\n
string is very big\n
i need to split it\n
into paragraph wise.\n
But this string\n
not a formated string.
```

but I want like this way:

```
This\n
1 string is very big\n
2 i need to split it\n
3 into paragraph wise.\n
4 But this string\n
5 not a formated string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python split() without removing the delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: delimiter will be inside in "content" string (ie number), we cant give before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.split` with forward lookahead:

```
import re
re.split('\s(?=\d\s)',content)
```

resulting in:

```
['This', '1 string is very big', '2 i need to split it', '3 into paragraph wise.', '4 But this string', '5 not a formated string.']
```

This splits on spaces -- but only those which are immediately followed by a digit then another space.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex module provided by python.
by `re.sub` you can find a regex group and replace it with your desired string. `\g<0>` is used to use the matched group ( in this case the numbers ).

Example:

```
import re

content = 'This 1 string is very big 2 i need to split it 3 into paragraph wise. 4 But this string 5 not a formated string.'
result = re.sub(r'\s\d\s',r'\n\g<0>',content)
```

Result would be :

```
'This\n 1 string is very big\n 2 i need to split it\n 3 into paragraph wise.\n 4 But this string\n 5 not a formated string.'
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is more in-depth details about `re.sub`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the output, iterate over it, and place your delimiters back where you want them? If the delimiters need to change each time, you could use the index of the loop that you use to iterate to decide what they are/need to be.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter) post useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import re
content = 'This 1 string is very big 2 i need to split it 3 into paragraph wise. 4 But this string 5 not a formated string.'
[ i.group(0).strip() for i in re.finditer('\S\d?[^\d]+', content)]
```

This one stops matching the string when it reaches a digit, but digits at the beginning are allowed.

Following is the output:

```
['This', '1 string is very big', '2 i need to split it', '3 into paragraph wise.', '4 But this string', '5 not a formated string.']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a question of new lines only, then use the string method splitlines() with keepends=True:

```
>>> "This\nis\na\ntest".splitlines(True)
["This\n", "is\n", "a\n", "test"]
```

Otherwise you can:

```
def split (s, d="\n"):
    d = str(d)
    if d=="": raise ValueError, "empty separator"
    f = s.find(d)
    if f==-1: return [s]
    l = []
    li = 0 # Last index
    add = len(d)
    while f!=-1:
        l.append(s[li:f+add])
        li = f+add
        f = s.find(d, li)
    e = s[li:]
    if e: l.append(e)
    return l
```