# Cutting of a sentence after trigger words

Tags: python

I have the following class with methods:

```
class Trigger():

    def getRidOfTrashPerSentence(self, line, stopwords):
        countWord = 0
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if countWord == 0:
                if word in stopwords:
                    sep = word
                    lineNew = line.split(sep, 1)[0]
                    countWord = countWord + 1
                    return(lineNew)

    stopwords = ['regards', 'Regards']

    def getRidOfTrash(self, aTranscript):
        result = [self.getRidOfTrashPerSentence(line, self.stopwords) for  line in aTranscript]
        return(result)
```

What I would like to achieve with it is to cut of 'trash' in sentence after certain trigger words like `['regards', 'Regards']`

So when I would insert a block like this:

```
aTranScript = [ "That's fine, regards Henk", "Allright great"]
```

I am looking for an output like this:

```
aTranScript = [ "That's fine, regards", "Allright great"]
```

However when I do this:

```
newFile = Trigger()
newContent = newFile.getRidOfTrash(aTranScript)
```

I only get `"That's fine"`.

Any thoughts on how I can get both the strings

Comment: How about you append the separator back after split? 

Here is a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter

Comment: I dont understand what you Vinay, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You can do this -
`lineNew = line.split(sep, 1)[0]`

`lineNew + = sep`

Answer (score 2):

this is an easy solution:

```
yourString = 'Hello thats fine, regards Henk'
yourString.split(', regards')[0]
```

This code will return: 'Hello thats fine'

If you want, you can concate 'regards' at the end:

yourString.split(', regards')[0]+', regards'

Comment: @EricDuminil you are rigth, change ', regards' for ' Henk' ;)

Comment: How would you adapt it to multiple trigger words?

Comment: You have a list of stopwords, you iterate over the list, when len(listAfterSplit)>1, you know the word you are spliting..

Answer (score 1):

Regex makes it easier to replace. As a bonus, it is case-insensitive so you don't have to write `'regards'` and `'Regards'` in your list :

```
import re

stop_words = ['regards', 'cheers']

def remove_text_after_stopwords(text, stop_words):
    pattern = "(%s).*$" % '|'.join(stop_words)
    remove_trash = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    return re.sub(remove_trash, '\g<1>', text)

print remove_text_after_stopwords("That's fine, regards, Henk", stop_words)
# That's fine, regards
print remove_text_after_stopwords("Good, cheers! Paul", stop_words)
# Good, cheers
print remove_text_after_stopwords("No stop word here", stop_words)
# No stop word here
```

If you have a list of strings, you can just use a list comprehension to apply this method over every string.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the words from the line and remove them if the previous word is a stopword:

```
class Trigger():

    stopwords = ['regards', 'Regards']

    def getRidOfTrashPerSentence(self, line):
        words = line.split()
        new_words = [words[0]]
        for i in range(1, len(words)):
            if not words[i-1] in self.stopwords:
                new_words.append(words[i])
        return " ".join(new_words)  # reconstruct line

    def getRidOfTrash(self, aTranscript):
        result = [self.getRidOfTrashPerSentence(line) for line in aTranscript]
        return(result)

aTranScript = [ "That's fine, regards Henk", "Allright great"]
newFile = Trigger()
newContent = newFile.getRidOfTrash(aTranScript)
print(newContent)
```