# Split text in Pandas and keep the delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split a series that has multiple values with file paths and jar file as a delimitator. How can split the values into different rows so that the '.jar' delimitator is not lost

Ex:
1    /opt/abc/defg/first.jar/opt/dce/efg/second.jar/opt/xyz/prs/third.jar

Expected result:
1    /opt/abc/defg/first.jar

2    /opt/dce/efg/second.jar

3    /opt/xyz/prs/third.jar

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Answer (score 3):

Try `str.split` with a *positive lookbehind assertion*

```
>>> df['path'].str.split('(?<=\.jar)').str[:-1].explode()

0    /opt/abc/defg/first.jar
0    /opt/dce/efg/second.jar
0     /opt/xyz/prs/third.jar
Name: path, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.str.extractall`, using the pattern **`'(.*?\.jar)'`**

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['/opt/abc/defg/first.jar/opt/dce/efg/second.jar/opt/xyz/prs/third.jar'])
s.str.extractall('(.*?\.jar)')
```

---

```
                               0
  match                         
0 0      /opt/abc/defg/first.jar
  1      /opt/dce/efg/second.jar
  2       /opt/xyz/prs/third.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `".jar"` after the split.

```
value = "/opt/abc/defg/first.jar/opt/dce/efg/second.jar/opt/xyz/prs/third.jar"
results = [i + ".jar" for i in value.split(".jar") if i != ""]
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['/opt/abc/defg/first.jar', '/opt/dce/efg/second.jar', '/opt/xyz/prs/third.jar']
```