# Splitting a string and retaining the separator (without RegEx)

Tags: python

I have the following string `foo`:

```
foo = 'F9B2Z1F8B30Z4'
```

**Without using `re`**, I'd like to split on 'F' and then add 'F' back to the resulting list.

My attempt is:

```
['F'+elem for elem in foo.split('F')]
```

This gives us:

```
['F', 'F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

But, I was expecting:

```
['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

Is it possible to modify the list comprehension to catch this case?  If not, is there another approach that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: `[f"F{elem}" for elem in foo.split("F") if elem]`

Comment: "Without using re" - why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter does not answer my question.  The suggested answer fails in certain cases.

Comment: Fails in what cases? Do you think that might be important information to include in your post?

Comment: Did you read all of the comments on that post? (I did)

Comment: Congrats. I'll ask again, fails in what cases? Did you try the "solution" I suggested in my first comment? We cannot help you solve a problem you refuse to describe.

Comment: @ddejohn: The answer there is straight-up wrong. Multiple comments there have provided failure cases. Your comment fails for similar reasons on similar cases.

Comment: Yes, your solution works in my case.  You asked if that post answers my question (it does not due to the edge cases that will fail).

Comment: Why don't you provide a sample string with such edge case?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, there are issues with this approach, but so far OP hasn't provided any evidence that it doesn't work for their specific use-case, which is incredibly vague. Not sure why OP is being cagey. Also not sure why regex isn't an option.

Comment: The deficiencies in the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter could affect me, hence this post.  Definitely not being "cagey" or vague.  At least not trying to be...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that more accurately represents the problem you are solving.

Comment: @equanimity could you please edit your question to provide a few more sample cases and make this question self sufficient?

Comment: So... after all that... you accepted an answer here that 1) uses regex, which you explicitly wanted to avoid, and 2) uses the exact same logic as the accepted answer in the duplicate you said didn't answer your question.

Comment: He appended a *non*-regex answer to his original answer.

Comment: Which is exactly the same as what I posted in the very first comment... which is also exactly the same as in that duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your problem might be more amenable to use `re.findall`:

```py
foo = 'F9B2Z1F8B30Z4'
parts = re.findall(r'F[^\WF]*', foo)
print(parts)  # ['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

The regex pattern matches a leading `F` followed by zero or more word characters, which are not `F`.

To do this using non regex split, we can slightly modify your list comprehension to only retain non empty string elements from the split:

```py
parts = ['F' + elem for elem in foo.split('F') if elem != '']
print(parts)  # ['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

Comment: While regex is what *should* be used here, OP explicitly requests a solution "without using re".

Comment: @ddejohn I didn't see that requirement.  I have added a non regex option to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex we can do it by replacing the F with some other delimiter before it then spiting it at the replaced delimiter and filtering empty strings

`[elem for elem in foo.replace("F","-F").split("-") if elem]`

Comment: What if my string is `"ABC-DEF-GHI"`?

Comment: You can use $  then

Comment: Not a fair comparison, since that's not the problem being solved.

Comment: Okay, what if my string is `"ABC-DEF$GHI"`? The point I'm trying to make is "replace your original delimiter with a different one" doesn't work for the general case because your new delimiter could be in your original string. You're much better off with just splitting on the original delimiter and adding it back into the string. Of course that still has problems as mentioned in the linked duplicate

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ok