# How to split a character in list and must still exist in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have list like

```
['a', 'pnp', 'a|pnp', 'lab2|pnp']
```

and I want to split them and have this

```
['a', 'pnp', 'a', '|', 'pnp', 'lab2', '|', 'pnp']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) here:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = ['a', 'pnp', 'a|pnp', 'lab2|pnp']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x.partition('|') if '|' in x else [x] for x in lst))
['a', 'pnp', 'a', '|', 'pnp', 'lab2', '|', 'pnp']
#or
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(filter(None, x.partition('|'))  for x in lst))
['a', 'pnp', 'a', '|', 'pnp', 'lab2', '|', 'pnp']
```

Here `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is used for flattening the list of lists(or tuples), and `str.partition` is used to split the string at the sep `|`:

```
>>> 'lab2|pnp'.partition('|')
('lab2', '|', 'pnp')
```

For items with the `sep` not present you'll have to use either `filter` or an conditional expression to handle the empty values of sep and tail:

```
>>> 'abc'.partition('|')
('abc', '', '')
>>> filter(None, 'abc'.partition('|'))
('abc',)
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is one way:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'pnp', 'a|pnp', 'lab2|pnp']
>>> list(itertools.chain(*(re.split("([|])", el) for el in l)))
['a', 'pnp', 'a', '|', 'pnp', 'lab2', '|', 'pnp']
```

For an explanation of `re.split("([|])", ...)`, see [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

`itertools.chain()` simply chains the results together, and `list()` converts the resulting iterable into a list.

Comment: Definitely more pythonic than my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a', 'pnp', 'a|pnp', 'lab2|pnp']
b = list()
for items in a:
  f = items.split('|')
  for z in range(len(f)-1):
      b.append(f[z])
      b.append('|')
  b.append(f[-1])

print(b)
['a', 'pnp', 'a', '|', 'pnp', 'lab2', '|', 'pnp']
```

Comment: Both of these methods throw away the `'|'` character, it looks like OP wants to keep those in the list.

Comment: The OP wants to have the pipe also in the list, splitting by `|` wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Also your second method creates list of lists

Comment: @EdChum: Removed the compact second method for now, since it was not giving the desired output anyhow.