# How to split string by space and treat special characters as a separate word in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have a string,

```
"I want that one, it is great."
```

I want to split up this string to be

```
["I", "want", "that", "one", ",", "it", "is", "great", "."]
```

Keeping special characters such as `",.:;"` and possibly other ones to be treated as a separate word.

Is there any easy way to do this with Python 2.7?

#### Update

For an example such as `"I don't."`, it should be `["I", "don", "'", "t", "."]`. It would ideally work with non-English punctuations such as `؛` and others.

Comment: how would you handle words like `"don't"`? Would you have `['don', ''', 't']`?

Comment: @RNar Yes, correct.

Comment: `[c for c in re.split('(\W+)', s) if c.strip() != '']`

Comment: I am not very experienced in Python, but in C# you would just use the string.Split() method with a character array containing a space and then the special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [70]: re.findall(r"[^,.:;' ]+|[,.:;']", "I want that one, it is great.")
Out[70]: ['I', 'want', 'that', 'one', ',', 'it', 'is', 'great', '.']

In [76]: re.findall(r"[^,.:;' ]+|[,.:;']", "I don't.")
Out[76]: ['I', 'don', "'", 't', '.']
```

The regex `[^,.:;' ]+|[,.:;']`  matches (1-or-more characters other than `,`, `.`, `:`, `;`, `'`  or a literal space), or (the literal characters `,`, `.`, `:`, `;`, or `'`).

---

Or, using the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you could easily expand this to include all [punctuation and symbols](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) by using the `[:punct:]` character class:

```
In [77]: import regex
```

In Python2:

```
In [4]: regex.findall(ur"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", u"""A \N{ARABIC SEMICOLON} B""")
Out[4]: [u'A', u'\u061b', u'B']

In [6]: regex.findall(ur"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", u"""He said, "I don't!" """)
Out[6]: [u'He', u'said', u',', u'"', u'I', u'don', u"'", u't', u'!', u'"']
```

In Python3:

```
In [105]: regex.findall(r"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", """A \N{ARABIC SEMICOLON} B""")
Out[105]: ['A', '؛', 'B']

In [83]: regex.findall(r"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", """He said, "I don't!" """)
Out[83]: ['He', 'said', ',', '"', 'I', 'don', "'", 't', '!', '"']
```

---

Note that it is important that you pass a `unicode` as the second argument to `regex.findall` if you wish `[:punct:]` to match unicode punctuation or symbols.

In Python2:

```
import regex
print(regex.findall(r"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", 'help؛'))
print(regex.findall(ur"[^[:punct:] ]+|[[:punct:]]", u'help؛'))
```

prints

```
['help\xd8\x9b']
[u'help', u'\u061b']
```

Comment: Will the second solution work for non-English punctuation such as `،`  and `؛`?

Comment: Indeed it does. When applied to unicode, `[:punct:]` is matches any unicode character in the [Punctuation \p{P} or Symbol \p{S} category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). See also, http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html.

Comment: This is going well. But the regex failed on this one `help؛`, the output was just the same string. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you passing a `unicode` as the second argument to `regex.findall`? I've added an example above showing what happens when a `str` (such as `'help؛'`) is passed instead of a `unicode` (such as `u'help؛'`). If this is the problem, then you can fix it by decoding the `str` with the appropriate encoding (e.g. `'help؛'.decode('utf-8')` ) to make a `unicode`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. How could you be so knowledgeable, patient and funny (I read your "About me") all at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136580/426790) for a similar question. The answer there applies to you as well:

```
import re
print re.split('(\W)', "I want that one, it is great.")
print re.split('(\W)', "I don't.")
```

You can remove the spaces and empty strings returned by `re.split` using a filter:

```
s = "I want that one, it is great."
print filter(lambda _: _ not in [' ', ''], re.split('(\W)', s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex and a simple list comprehension to do this. The regex will pull out words and separate punctuation, and the list comprehension will remove the blank spaces.

```
import re
s = "I want that one, it is great. Don't do it."
new_s = [c.strip() for c in re.split('(\W+)', s) if c.strip() != '']
print new_s
```

The output of `new_s` will be:

```
['I', 'want', 'that', 'one', ',', 'it', 'is', 'great', '.', 'Don', "'", 't', 'do', 'it', '.']
```

Comment: This is promising but is there a way to trim strings to avoid extra spaces in `", "`

Comment: @M-T-A yes, just fixed

Comment: @EoinS I just fixed that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any functions that can do this but you could use a for loop.

Something like this:
    word = ""
    wordLength = 0 
    for i in range(0, len(stringName)):
      if stringName[i] != " ":
          for x in range((i-wordLength), i):
               word += stringName[i]
               wordLength = 0
          list.append(word)
          word = ""
      else:
          worldLength = wordlength + 1
Hope this works...sorry if it is not the best way