# python split string but keep delimiter

Tags: python, string, file

In python I can easily read a file line by line into a set, just be using:

```
file = open("filename.txt", 'r')
content = set(file)
```

each of the elements in the set consists of the actual line and also the trailing line-break.

Now I have a string with multiple lines, which I want to compare to the content by using the normal set operations.

Is there any way of transforming a string into a `set` just the same way, such, that it also contains the line-breaks?

---

Edit:

The question ["In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) deals with a similar problem, but the answer doesn't make it easy to adopt to other use-cases.

```
import re
content = re.split("(\n)", string)
```

doesn't have the expected effect.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Would it be easier to write file.read().split('\n') and compare that to your string?

Comment: Most of the time the wright thing to do is to ignore white space, you can do `set(line.strip() for line in file)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: @xenteros actually not, because the answers there are not very portable to other use-cases. I've added a statement to that in the bottom part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple generator that does the job:

```
content = set(e + "\n" for e in s.split("\n"))
```

This solution adds an additional newline at the end though.

Comment: Worse than adding a newline to the last line if it didn't have one already, this code adds an entire extra string with only a newline in it if the last line of the original text *did* have a trailing newline. So if `s` is `"foo\nbar\n\baz\n"`, your code will make `content` into a set equal to `{'foo\n', 'bar\n', 'baz\n', '\n'}`.

Answer (score 7):

The [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method does exactly what you want if you pass `True` as the optional `keepends` parameter. It keeps the newlines on the end of each line, and doesn't add one to the last line if there was no newline at the end of the string.

```
text = "foo\nbar\nbaz"
lines = text.splitlines(True)
print(lines) # prints ['foo\n', 'bar\n', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it the other way round, remove line endings when reading file lines, assuming you open the file with `U` for universal line endings:

```
file = open("filename.txt", 'rU')
content = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you mean?

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> someLines=StringIO('''\
... line1
... line2
... line3
... ''')
>>> content=set(someLines)
>>> content
{'line1\n', 'line2\n', 'line3\n'}
```