# How to split string and pipe to separate files in python

Tags: android, python

I am having some trouble figuring out how to split a string in a text file and separate the strings into separate files

Within the text file I have the following:

```
package:/system/app/CustomLocale/CustomLocale.apk=com.android.customlocale2
package:/system/app/Gallery2/Gallery2.apk=com.android.gallery3d
package:/system/app/Calendar/Calendar.apk=com.android.calendar
```

And I have the following code:

```
import os

os.system("adb shell pm list packages -f > apps.txt")

f = open('apps.txt',"r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        #print(word)
        if word.startswith('.apk'):
            print(word)
```

Now I understand how to split each line up indivdually and pipe them into a file however i would like to implement a way to split the first part of the string which is "package:/system/app/CustomLocale/CustomLocale" from the second part which is ".apk=com.android.calendar". How would I start to implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is your best friend for cases like this in general. For this particular case, use [str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) parameters to your advantage.

```
line.split('.', 1)
['package:/system/app/CustomLocale/CustomLocale','apk=com.android.customlocale2']

line.split('.apk=', 1)
['package:/system/app/CustomLocale/CustomLocale', 'com.android.customlocale2']
```

In this way, you can split the whole string on whatever you need, limit the split to however many breaks you want to make, and then use that however you need.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think this is what you need: [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

And, for this case,

```
import re

f = open('apps.txt',"r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    ret = re.split('(\.apk)', line)
    print ret[0]
    print ret[1]+ret[2]
```

The result is:

```
 package:/system/app/CustomLocale/CustomLocale
 .apk=com.android.customlocale2

package:/system/app/Gallery2/Gallery2
.apk=com.android.gallery3d

package:/system/app/Calendar/Calendar
.apk=com.android.calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution.
output is written to out1.txt   (string before .apk) and out2.txt (after and including .apk)

```
import os
out1 = open('out1.txt', 'w')
out2 = open('out2.txt', 'w')
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
pat='.apk'
for line in lines:
    line=line.rstrip()
    x=line.split(pat,1)
    out1.write(x[0]) 
    out1.write('\n') 
    out2.write(pat)      
    out2.write(x[1])      
    out2.write('\n')      
out1.close()
out2.close()
f.close()
```