# Python Cutting a string on a certain point

Tags: python, string, split

Ok so i'll explain what i have and need to do.

I have a dict with multiple keys but i'll give one for this example and a string made up of A, T, C and G. (the [3:] indicating it should split on the 3 index of the value)

```
Dict = {'EcoRV': 'GATATC'[3:]} 
String = 'AAAAGATATCAAAGATATCAAAA'
```

Now here is what i need to do. I have to look for the value in the string and split the string on the value of the dict key and end up with a list containing the part where it split, so in this case it would have to split on 'TC' and take the first C and split it and end up with:

```
List = ['AAAAGATA','TCAAAGATA','TCAAAA']
```

I tried it with `split` but it loses the `'TC'` and I need to keep those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: @Pit I do not see the connection.

Comment: What is that `[1]` doing there on the dict?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I glossed over the resulting list, this is in fact not a duplicate of the answer I linked. Sorry!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It's an indication for where it should split. It should look for the sequence of letters TC and split between the T and C so the [1] indicates that.

Comment: @NathanWeesie What the `[1]` does is that it indexes your `"TC"` string and converts it to `"C"`. So remove it.

Comment: @NathanWeesie your edited example still won't do what you want it to - Python will evaluate `'GATATC'[3:]` to `'ATC'`, and then you lose the preceding data. I've provided an example dictionary structure in my answer that might work for you.

Answer (score 5):

You've seen how split can work - how about you add an arbitrary character that you won't find in your string between the letters you want to separate, and split on that:

```
test_str = 'AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGGAAA'
print test_str.replace('TC', 'T:C').split(':')
```

prints `['AAATTT', 'CCCGGGT', 'CGGGAAA']`.

If you want to extend this further using your dictionary, you can change the `replace` parameters to use your dictionary values with string formatting. For example:

```
temp_dict = {'Testenzyme': 'TC',
             'Asongtoruinzine': 'GA'}

test_str = 'AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGGAAA'

out_dict = dict()

for key, val in temp_dict.items():
    out_dict[key] = test_str.replace(val, '{}:{}'.format(val[0], val[1])).split(':')

print out_dict
```

prints `{'Asongtoruinzine': ['AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGG', 'AAA'], 'Testenzyme': ['AAATTT', 'CCCGGGT', 'CGGGAAA']}`

EDIT: Reading the comments I see you want to specify where to split the string in the dictionary values. It would be easier if you wrote your dictionary values as two-element lists, where the two elements represented the different parts of the string you wanted to split. For example, you could then do the following:

```
temp_dict = {'Testenzyme': ['T', 'C'],
             'Asongtoruinzine': ['GT', 'C']}

test_str = 'AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGGAAA'

out_dict = dict()

for key, val in temp_dict.items():
    out_dict[key] = test_str.replace(''.join(val), ':'.join(val)).split(':')

print out_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
enzyme= 'TC'
String = 'AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGGAAA'

import re

#with re.split:
print(list( filter(bool, re.split(r'(.*?{})(?={})'.format(enzyme[0], enzyme[1]), String)) ))

#alternative with re.findall:
print( re.findall(r'.*?{}(?={})|.+$'.format(enzyme[0], enzyme[1]), String) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
Dict = {'Testenzyme':'TC'}
String = 'AAATTTCCCGGGTCGGGAAA'
TestEnzyme = Dict['Testenzyme']
String.replace(TestEnzyme , re.sub(r'(\w)(\w)', r'\1:\2', TestEnzyme )).split(":")
```

should do the job