# Why do Regex groups in Python not get matched as expected?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Python seems to have a rather surprising behavior when matching groups in Python:

```
>>> re.split("\+|-", "1+2")
['1', '2']

>>> re.split("(\+|-)", "1+2")
['1', '+', '2']
```

I haven't found any satisfying explanation for why grouping a single expression would prevent it from being matched, so what's the problem here?

According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) there is absolutely no difference when it comes to matching, although more steps are required.
[image: regex test]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators. And [`re.split` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split): *If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `()`, you are asking Python to 'capture' that value in the split.

Like if you were to do:

```
>>> re.split("(a\+|-)", "1a+2")
['1', 'a+', '2']
```

Then it would fetch a+ and put it in the center.

What is happening it it is taking all the captured groupings and putting them in the array between relevant items, like in this example:

```
>>> re.split("(a)(\+|-)", "1a+2")
['1', 'a', '+', '2']
```