# Mathematical operations of user submitted equation

Tags: python

I am writing a program to take an equation from the user for example `2 * 56` and the program gives out the answer. this is working but for more than 2 function my code breaks

```
equation = input('Enter an equation: ')

def addition():
    splited = equation.split('+')
    results = [float(i) for i in splited]
    results = results[0] + results[1]
    print(results)

def subtraction():
    splited= equation.split('-')
    results = [float(i) for i in splited]
    results = results[0] - results[1]
    print(results)

def multiply():
    splited= equation.split('*')
    results = [float(i) for i in splited]
    results = results[0] * results[1]
    print(results)

def divide():
    splited= equation.split('/')
    results = [float(i) for i in splited]
    results = results[0] / results[1]
    print(results)

if ('+') in equation:
    addition()
elif ('-') in equation:
    subtraction()
elif ('*') in equation:
    multiply()
elif ('/') in equation:
    divide()
else:
    print('Error! Please only input + , - , * , /')
```

this code easily works for equations containing only one operation but what if user inputs `2 + 2 - 9 * 6` how can i modify this code to work with every case possible

Comment: consider recursion

Comment: Expressions, not equations.

Comment: You also need to consider precedence if you are going to fully implement something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you are expression equation to consists only one operator and 2 operand, when there are more operator, results = `result[0] + result[1]` will evaluate to this `results[0] = 2`, `results[1] = 2 - 9 * 6`. Therefore you are getting such an error.

The below program evaluates from right to left. recursively iterate through each operand or operator of the expression. Understand [re.split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) and capture groups before jumping into the solution.

```
import re

def evaluate(expression, index, size, result):
    if index == 0:
        operand = float(expression[0])
        return evaluate(expression, index + 1, size, operand)
    elif index < size:
        op = expression[index]
        if op in ['+', '-', '/', '*']:
            if op == '+':
                return result + evaluate(expression, index +1, size, 0.0)
            if op == '-':
                return result - evaluate(expression, index +1, size, 0.0)
            if op == '/':
                return result / evaluate(expression, index +1, size, 0.0)
            if op == '*':
                return result * evaluate(expression, index +1, size, 0.0)
        else:
            return evaluate(expression, index +1, size, float(op))
    else:
        return result

expression = re.split('([+-/*])', '2+34-48/8')
size = len(expression)
print evaluate(expression, 0, size, 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but an extremely simple way to do it is this:

```
equation = input('Enter an equation: ')
print(eval(equation))
```

Comment: [**Eval really is dangerous.**](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @zwer I'm assuming the program is getting valid input from the user as the original program would crash as well with invalid input. we aren't doing anything with the eval output, just printing it.

Comment: A user can easily be tricked to type `__import__('os').system('find ~ -exec rm -r "{}" \;')` and pop, goes the weasel, and the user's home directory with it... Non-programmers should never be exposed to code, especially not the one capable of running at a system level.

Comment: @zwer Again, I'm assuming the input is controlled in this case.