# Split string while retaining whitespace separators

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string, but keep all separators bundled together in a separate list.

```
s = "This is a test     for \n a string"
```

should results in

```
a = ["This", "is", "a", "test", "for", "a", "string"]
b = [" ", " ", " ", "     ", " \n ", " "]
```

Any idea on how to handle that?

Comment: Downvoters, it isn't _that_ bad a question. The problem statement is clear and the question is answerable.

Comment: How do you define *separators*? Is it everything that is not a word? How would the result look like if your text string ended with `.`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators/34004805?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) is your friend:

```
split = re.split(r'(\s+)', s)   
x = split[::2]
y = split[1::2]
```

```
>>> x
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'a', 'string']
>>> y
[' ', ' ', ' ', '     ', ' \n ', ' ']
```