# python re.split(): how to save some of the delimiters (instead of all the delimiter by using bracket)

Tags: python, split

For the sentences:

```
"I am very hungry,    so mum brings me a cake!
```

I want it split by delimiters, and I want all the delimiters except space to be saved as well. So the expected output is :

```
"I"  "am"  "very"  "hungry"   ","   "so", "mum"  "brings"  "me"   "a"   "cake"    "!"    "\n"
```

What I am currently doing is `re.split(r'([!:''".,(\s+)\n])', text)`,  which split the whole sentences but also saved a lot of space characters which I don't want.  I've also tried the regular expression `\s|([!:''".,(\s+)\n])` , which gives me a lot of None somehow.

Comment: Almost(?) a duplicate of [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` or `findall` might be more appropriate here than `split`:

```
import re

s = "I am very hungry,    so mum brings me a !#$#@  cake!"

print(re.findall(r'[^\w\s]+|\w+', s))

# ['I', 'am', 'very', 'hungry', ',', 'so', 'mum', 'brings', 'me', 'a', '!#$#@', 'cake', '!']
```

The pattern `[^\w\s]+|\w+` means: a sequence of symbols which are neither alphanumeric nor whitespace OR a sequence of alphanumerics (that is, a word)

Comment: could you explain a little bit how the pattern is constructed this way ?   why [^\w\s]+  gives all the words but not words with space character (as \s suggested)?  Also why you put  |w+  pattern there ?

Comment: @SoManyProblems: added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

That is because your regular expression contains a capture group. Because of that capture group, it will also include the matches in the result. But this is likely what you want.

The only challenge is to `filter` out the `None`s (and other values with truthiness `False`) in case there is no match, we can do this with:

```
def tokenize(text):
    return filter(None, re.split(r'[ ]+|([!:''".,\s\n])', text))
```

For your given sample text, this produces:

```
>>> list(tokenize("I am very hungry,    so mum brings me a cake!\n"))
['I', 'am', 'very', 'hungry', ',', 'so', 'mum', 'brings', 'me', 'a', 'cake', '!', '\n']
```

Comment: why adding the [ ]+|  into the reg expression would lead to generating a lot of Nones ?  I

Comment: @SoManyProblems: because if the capture group (the part in the parenthesis), does not matches anything, it still introduces a `None` for "empty" capture groups. If you generate multiple parenthesis, this can even result in a lot of extra elements.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.  Just to confirm that I understand you correctly,  do you mean that [ ]+ matches the space, so it did the split work, and because it doesn't have a (), so it would returns None back ?

Comment: @SoManyProblems: the regex itself has a `(...)`, a capture group. But since that capture group is *not* "activated" (it ddoes not matches anything), it captures `None`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to surround the special characters `(,!.\n)` with space and then split on space:

```
import re


def tokenize(t, pattern="([,!.\n])"):
    return [e for e in re.sub(pattern, r" \1 ", t).split(' ') if e]


s = "I am very hungry,    so mum brings me a cake!\n"

print(tokenize(s))
```

**Output**

```
['I', 'am', 'very', 'hungry', ',', 'so', 'mum', 'brings', 'me', 'a', 'cake', '!', '\n']
```