# Python, Beautiful soup, <br> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

So I have looked through stack overflow but I cannot seem to find an answer to my problem. How do I get the text, specific text, after a < br > tag?

This is my Code:

```
product_review_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"search_review_summary"})
for product_review in product_review_container:
    prr = product_review.get('data-tooltip-html')
    print(prr)
```

This is the output:

```
Very Positive<br>86% of the 1,013 user reviews for this game are positive.
```

I want in this string only the 86% and also seperatly only the 1,013. So the numbers only. However it is not an int so I do not know what to do.

Here is where the text comes from:

```
   [<span class="search_review_summary positive" data-tooltip-html="Very Positive&lt;br&gt;86% of the 1,013 user reviews for this game are positive.">
</span>]
```

Here is the link from where I am getting the information: https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1

Thank you!

Comment: you can use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regex here!

```
import re

string = 'Very Positive<br>86% of the 1,013 user reviews for this game are positive.'
a = re.findall('(\d+%)|(\d+,\d+)',string)
print(a)

output: [('86%', ''), ('', '1,013')]
#Then a[0][0] will be 86% and a[1][1] will be 1,013
```

Where \d is any number character in the string, and the + is there are at least 1 or more digits.

If you need more specific regex then you can trying it in https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks! this worked, I had a little problem with the , in between 1,013. had to make it into a . (dot) and then do replace(",","") but it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a non-regex way to do it; admittedly somewhat convoluted, but still fun:

First, we borrow (and modify) [this nice function:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120478/9448090)

```
def split_and_keep(s, sep):
         if not s: return [''] # consistent with string.split()
         p=chr(ord(max(s))+1)
         return s.replace(sep, sep+p).split(p)
```

Then we go through some standard steps:

```
html = """
  [<span class="search_review_summary positive" data-tooltip-html="Very    Positive&lt;br&gt;86% of the 1,013 user reviews for this game are positive."></span>]
  """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
soup = bs4(html, 'html.parser')
info = soup.select('span')[0].get("data-tooltip-html")
print(info)
```

Output so far, is:

```
Very Positive<br>86% of the 1,013 user reviews for this game are positive.
```

Next we go:

```
data = ''.join(c for c in info if (c.isdigit()) or c == '%')
print(data)
```

Output is a little better now:

```
86%1013
```

Almost there; now the *pièce de résistance*:

```
split_and_keep(data, '%')
```

Final output:

```
['86%', '1013']
```