# Matching alphanumeric words, mentions or emails with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) and [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex) and lots of others. They don't answer to my problem.

I'd like to filter a string that may contain emails **or** strings starting by "@" (like emails but without the text before the "@"). I've tested many ones but one of the simplest that begins to get close is:

```
import re
re.split(r'(@)', "test @aa test2 @bb @cc t-es @dd-@ee, test@again")
Out[40]: 
['test ', '@', 'aa test2 ', '@', 'bb ', '@', 'cc t-es ', '@', 'dd-', '@', 'ee, test', '@', 'again']
```

I'm looking for the right regexp that could give me:

```
['test ', '@aa', 'test2 ', '@bb ', '@cc', 't-es ', '@dd-', '@ee', 'test@again']
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `'@ee', 'test@again'` and not `'@ee, test@again'` (single item)? Should the comma be considered as a "stop" char?

Comment: Maybe `r'(?=\B@)|\s*,\s*'` will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nope it gives me one item like `@aa test2 ` whereas I should have 2 items: `@aa` and `test2`

Comment: Then please check your question and edit. We do not know what result you expect and why.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I'm looking exactly for `@aa`, `@bb`, `@dd-`, `@ee`, `test@again`

Comment: Does `re.findall(r'[^\s@]*@[^\s@]+', s)` work for you? If not, why? Please explain the rules in the question.

Comment: The questions you menioned did not work for you because you had quite a different  problem, it is not about splitting with some delimiters to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution based on different email parsing + simple "`@[:alphanum:]+`" parsing is:

```
USERNAME_OR_EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(
    r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"  # simple username
    r"|"
    r"[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+"  # email 
    r"@"  # following: domain name:
    r"[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?"
    r"(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why try to split when you can go "yo regex, give me all that matches":

```
test = "test @aa test2 @bb @cc t-es @dd-@ee, test@again"


import re

print(
    re.findall("[^\s@]*?@?[^@]* |[^@]*@[^\s@]*", test)
)
# ['test ', '@aa test2 ', '@bb ', '@cc t-es ', '@dd-', '@ee, ', 'test@again']
```

I tried but I couldn't make the regex any smaller, but at least it works and who expects regex to be small anyway

---

As per the OP's new requirements(or corrected requirements)

```
[^\s@]*?@?[^\s@]* |[^@]*@[^\s@]*
```

Comment: You are on the right path, but I was wrong in my question, I've edited it, could you check it again? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to decide `'@aa test2 '` you either get this, or `'@cc', 't-es '` this, if we are gonna split on the white space like the second, first one would get split too, if we want them together, the second one would be together too.

Comment: OMG I was wrong again, sorry, I've edited it, could you check it again? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm almost there: `re.findall("[^@\s]*@[^\[@!\?\]\s]*", "test. @aa test2 t-es @dd-@ee, @ff. @ff! test@again.com ns@gmail.com")` but I want to stop before unwanted chars like `!` or `?`

Comment: It matches all you want, what is the problem? do you want match the `!` too or what?

Comment: it's the contrary: i want to match only good email chars, and *even though* I've excluded "by hand" the `!` and the `?` I think this is not a good solution. The idea would be: "you keep emails through a good regexp *or* `@xxx` too"

Comment: It is hard to re-write the regex every time you want to add a new qualifier. Instead you should've started with this, `I want emails, and emails without the part before @ symbol` Anyway, give this `[\w.+-]*@[\w.+-]*` a shot

Comment: I've checked your answer it's good I check it as valid, and I've posted mine as well. Have a good day!