# Separate values in a list by comma in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python in which I need to separate a value to multiple values using comma.

Below is my sample input list:

```
print(lt) #lt is a list

['New film released yesterday\nMovie will be released tomorrow\n
People will watch in theatres\n Movie is very bad\nIt can be good \n\n 
But the director flopped it\n Movie is good']
```

I have a single value in the above list. I need to insert comma(,) inside it to separate them to multiple values if I find `Movie` in the list.

Expected output:

```
 ['New film released yesterday\n','Movie will be released tomorrow\n
    People will watch in theatres\n','Movie is very bad\nIt can be good \n\n 
    But the director flopped it\n ','Movie is good']
```

Here you can see the the list having single value has been split to multiple values using `comma (,)`.
Please explain how to solve this issue.Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators

Comment: `lt[0].replace('Movie', ',Movie').split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

```
lt=lt[0].replace('Movie', ',Movie').split(',')
```

This gives the right output.

```
['New film released yesterday\n','Movie will be released tomorrow\n
    People will watch in theatres\n','Movie is very bad\nIt can be good \n\n 
    But the director flopped it\n ','Movie is good']
```