# How to slice parts of a text file into a new one

Tags: python, slice, txt

I am analyzing a text file filled with monologues and I would like to create a separate text file composed of monologues from a single character.

Here's an example:

PERSON A:

Hi

PERSON B:

Hello

My goal is to slice all monologues from Person A into a new text. I've been battling with this for hours but I have no clue. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Think about which character or string separates the speeches of the persons. Use the split function and keep the delimiter. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split and [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators). Then think about how you can identify the speeches of the persons in the result of the split function. When you can identify them separate them and write them to a file.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good strategy!