# How can I use Regex to return a string with its matches PLUS its delimiters?

Tags: python

For example, I want to take a weirdly formatted expression: `'4.2+5 - 6'`
and return this list: `['4.2', '+', '5', '-', '6]`

I can return `['4.2', '5', '6']` but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) In your case: `re.split('([+-])', '4.2+5 - 6')`

Comment: You should provide a description of what input you are expecting. You just provided one example. Make sure to include all edge cases!

Comment: It's hard to answer with a single example. Does this work for you? `\d+(\.\d+)?|\+|\-`