# Python: Split string without losing split character

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, python-3.9

`string = 'Hello.World.!'`

*My Try*

```
string.split('.')
```

*Output*

> ['Hello', 'World', '!']

**Goal Output**

> ['Hello', '.', 'World', '.', '!']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in a single line:

```py
string = "HELLO.WORLD.AGAIN."
pattern = "."
result = string.replace(pattern, f" {pattern} ").split(" ")
# if you want to omit the last element because of the punctuation at the end of the string uncomment this
# result = result[:-1]
```

Comment: the best one so far

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```py
string = 'Hello.World.!'

result = []
for word in string.split('.'):
    result.append(word)
    result.append('.')

# delete the last '.'
result = result[:-1]
```

You can also delete the last element of the list like that:

```
result.pop()
```

Comment: Deletion can be done by `result.pop()` rather than array slicing to create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

Use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and put a capturing group around the separator:

```
import re
string = 'Hello.World.!'

re.split(r'(\.)', string)
# ['Hello', '.', 'World', '.', '!']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.split()`, with first arg as your delimiter.

```
import re

print(re.split("(\.)", "hello.world.!"))
```

Backslash is to escape the “.” as it is a special character in regex, and parentheses to capture the delimiter as well.

Related question: [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)