# Python Split/Slice a string into a list while keeping delimeter

Tags: python, string, list

I want to take a string and create a list from it using a delimiter, while keeping delimiter.

If I have `"A56-3#AJ4klAP0W"` I would like to return a list with A as delimiter.

```
[A56-3#, AJ4kl, AP0W]
```

I have tried split and slice but have not been successful.
I did do list comprehension to get a list of the index of each delimiter but haven't been able to do much with it [0, 6, 11]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: Is "A" really a *delimiter*, or do you want substrings starting with "A"?

Comment: I believe you are correct, this should be substring, not delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it back in:

```
>>> x = 'A56-3#AJ4klAP0W'
>>> x.split('A')
['', '56-3#', 'J4kl', 'P0W']
>>> ['A'+k for k in x.split('A') if k]
['A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
>>>
```

Comment: This only works if the delimiter is the first character. For `x = '56-3#AJ4klAP0W'`, there's an extra `A` at the start of the first string

Comment: The OP will have to clarify the requirements.  I'm guessing from the question that the string WILL always start with an A.

Comment: The string can start with any item. This does work when string starts with Delimiter. I can handle the problem when string doesn't start with delimiter. Thank you for all the wonderful help

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions and the [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function.

```
>>> re.findall('A?[^A]+', 'A56-3#AJ4klAP0W')
['A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
```

This even works when the string *doesn't* start with your delimiter. E.g.

```
>>> re.findall('A?[^A]+', '56-3#AJ4klAP0W')
['56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
```

Explanation: ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NaLslA/1))

```
A?      : Zero or one "A"
  [^A]+ : Followed by one or more "not A"
```

It's easy to build the regex using an f-string:

```
def get_substrings(delim, s):
    rex = f"{delim}?[^{delim}]+"
    return re.findall(rex, s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
st="A56-3#AJ4klAP0W"
```

You can get the index of each delimiter with enumerate:

```
idx=[i for i,ch in enumerate(st) if ch=='A']
```

Then slice the string with that index:

```
>>> [st[x:y] for x,y in zip([0]+idx, idx[1:]+[len(st)])]
['A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
# this is how you use the [0,6,11] list in your question
```

You can also use a regex split:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?=A)', st)
['', 'A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
```

Or find the substrings (rather than split) that satisfy that condition:

```
>>> re.findall(r'A*[^A]+', st)
['A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well and works if the string doesn't start with delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> [f'A{el}' for el in "A56-3#AJ4klAP0W".split('A') if el]
['A56-3#', 'AJ4kl', 'AP0W']
>>>
```