# Python split() without removing the delimiter in a list

Tags: python, pyspark, split, python-re

We have this list:

```
lista = ['int32',
 'decimal(14)',
 'int(32)',
 'string',
 'date',
 'decimal(27,2)',
 'decimal(17,2)']
```

And we need:

```
['int32', 'decimal', '(14)',
 'int', '(32)',
 'string',
 'date',
 'decimal','(27,2)',
 'decimal','(17,2)']
```

We use

```
for i in lista:
    .split('(')
```

but we lose `(` in the process.

Comment: But since you know that `'('` has been removed you can easily add it back.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works this code :)

```
lista = ['int32','decimal(14)','int(32)','string','date','decimal(27,2)','decimal(17,2)']
lst = []
for i in lista:
    x= (i.find('('))
    if(x != -1):
        lst.append(i[0:x])
        lst.append(i[x::])
    else:
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```