# How to retain delimiter within list item python

Tags: python, list, delimiter

I'm writing a program which jumbles clauses within a text using punctuation marks as delimiters for when to split the text.

At the moment my code has a large list where each item is a group of clauses.

```
import re
from random import shuffle
clause_split_content = []

text = ["this, is. a test?", "this: is; also. a test!"]

for i in text:
        clause_split = re.split('[,;:".?!]', i)
        clause_split.remove(clause_split[len(clause_split)-1])
        for x in range(0, len(clause_split)):
                clause_split_content.append(clause_split[x])
shuffle(clause_split_content)
print(*content, sep='')
```

at the moment the result jumbles the text without retaining the punctuation which is used as the delimiter to split it.
The output would be something like this:

```
a test this also this is a test is
```

I want to retain the punctuation within the final output so it would look something like this:

```
a test! this, also. this: is. a test? is;
```

Comment: Why split it on the punctuation? Can't you just take each index in the list and append it as a single string?

Comment: In my program each item in the list is a line of text within a larger text. However, within each line there is punctuation which I need to be able split further.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question. Is the answer below close?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are simply using the wrong function of `re` for your purpose. `split()` excludes your separator, but you can use another function e.g. `findall()` to manually select all words you want. For example with the following code I can create your desired output:

```
import re
from random import shuffle

clause_split_content = []

text = ["this, is. a test?", "this: is; also. a test!"]

for i in text:
    words_with_seperator = re.findall(r'([^,;:".?!]*[,;:".?!])\s?', i)
    clause_split_content.extend(words_with_seperator)
    
shuffle(clause_split_content)
print(*clause_split_content, sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
this, this: is. also. a test! a test? is;
```

The pattern `([^,;:".?!]*[,;:".?!])\s?` simply takes all characters that are not a separator until a separator is seen. These characters are all in the matching group, which creates your result. The `\s?` is only to get rid of the space characters in between the words.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do what you've asked:

```py
import re
from random import shuffle
text = ["this, is. a test?", "this: is; also. a test!"]
content = [y for x in text for y in re.findall(r'([^,;:".?!]*[,;:".?!])', x)]
shuffle(content)
print(*content, sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
 is;  is.  also.  a test? this,  a test! this:
```

Explanation:

- the regex pattern `r'([^,;:".?!]*[,;:".?!])'` matches 0 or more non-separator characters followed by a separator character, and [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of all such non-overlapping matches
- the list comprehension iterates over the input strings in list `text` and has an inner loop that iterates over the `findall` results for each input string, so that we create a single list of every matched pattern within every string.
- `shuffle` and `print` are as in your original code.

Comment: @user7266757 Do you need more help with this question?