# How to split text according to multiple string separators/delimiters and keep them in the output?

Tags: python, string

I want to implement the following in python.

Given the input:

```
Text = 'ABC-363738743DEF-2746824769ABC-48738383DEF-437833892'
```

I want to split this text based on 'ABC' and 'DEF', but also keep them in the output, so I need this:

```
['ABC-363738743','DEF-2746824769','ABC-48738383','DEF-437833892']
```

If I use `split()` then it deletes ABC and DEF.

Could anyone explain to me how I can get this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code:

```
import re 
Text = 'ABC-363738743DEF-2746824769ABC-48738383DEF-437833892'

[ 'A'+i if i.startswith('B') and (len(i)>1) else 'D'+i  for i  in re.split('A|D', Text) ][1:]
```

Output:

[image]