# Splitting String Using RE findall () in Python using ']]' as delimiter but keeping the delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, split

Simplest way to explain will be I have this code,

```
Str = 'Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_1: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5], [-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5]]Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_2: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5], [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_3: [[-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5], [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]'
from re import findall

findall ('[^\]\]]+\]\]?', Str)
```

What I get is,

```
['Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_1: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5]',
 ', [-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5]]',
 'Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_2: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5]',
 ', [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]',
 'Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_3: [[-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5]',
 ', [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]']
```

I assume it's taking only single ']' instead of ']]' when splitting, I want result as below,

```
['Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_1: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5], [-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5]]',
 'Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_2: [[-3, 0, 0, 5.5], [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]',
 'Floor_Live_Patterened_SpanPairs_3: [[-3, 5.5, 0, 9.5], [-3, 9.5, 0, 13.5]]']
```

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't work out how to achieve this or what modification should be done in above using regex findall function, a similar technique was adopted in one of answers in [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: How about just [`.+?\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/najFQq/1)

Comment: thank you so much bobble bubble, this '.' character saved me :)

Comment: Use a proper serialization format in the first place to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to use a [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.+?` until `]]`. The dot matches any character (besides newline). Using a *non-greedy* (lazy) [quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) will match as least characters for the rest of the pattern to succeed.

```
.+?\]\]
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/najFQq/1) (more explanation on the right side)

Be aware that `[^\]\]]+` does not match substrings that are not `]]`. Would be the same functioning if you removed one of the closing brackets. Read more [about character classes here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to match *balanced* bracket constructs, a more robust solution would be to use a regex engine that supports recursion, such as the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, and use the `(?R)` pattern to recursively match balanced pairs of brackets:

```
import regex

regex.findall(r'.*?\[(?>[^[\]]|(?R))*\]', Str)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/TroubledTurboLint