# Splitting a string into multiple string using re.split()

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string that I am trying to split into 2 strings using Regex to form a list. Below is the string:

Input: `'TLSD_IBPDEq.'`

Output: `['', '']`

Expected Output: `['TLSD_IBPD', 'Eq.']`

Below is what I have tried but is not working

```
pattern = r"\S*Eq[\.,]"
l = re.split(pattern,"TLSD_IBPDEq.")

print(l)  => ['', '']
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? Can you explain what you want the RegEx to do?

Comment: Do you want only match string that ends with `Eq.` and then make 2-item list?

Comment: pattern = r'Eq\.'

Comment: I want to split input string which in this case is "TLSD_IBPDEq." into 2 based on a match which is "Eq."

Comment: Yes I only want to match string that ends with "Eq." and make them into 2 item list

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, then you can apply the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators). If you need to use a regex to solve this, then use a capture group and remove the last (empty) element, like this:

```
pattern = r"(Eq\.)$"
l = re.split(pattern, "TLSD_IBPDEq.")[:-1]
print(l)  # => ['TLSD_IBPD', 'Eq.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `re`:

```py
s = "TLSD_IBPDEq."

if s.endswith(("Eq.", "Eq,")):
    print([s[:-3], s[-3:]])
```

Prints:

```
['TLSD_IBPD', 'Eq.']
```

---

Solution with `re`:

```py
import re

s = "TLSD_IBPDEq."

print(list(re.search(r"(\S*)(Eq[.,])$", s).groups()))
```

Prints:

```
['TLSD_IBPD', 'Eq.']
```