# How to split a string but keep multiple delimiters with the original chunk

Tags: python

Say my string is

```
st = 'Walking happened at 8 am breakfast happened at 9am baseball happened at 12 pm lunch happened at 1pm'
```

I would like to split on 'am' or 'pm', but I want those deliminters to be a part of the original chunk.

So the desired result is

```
splitlist = ['Walking happened at 8 am',
             'breakfast happened at 9am',
             'baseball happened at 12 pm',
             'lunch happened at 1pm']
```

There are many solutions for keeping the delimiter, but keeping it as a separate item in the list like this one

[In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind:

```
import re

splitlist = re.split(r'(?<=[ap]m)\s+', st)
```

Output:

```
['Walking happened at 8 am',
 'breakfast happened at 9am',
 'baseball happened at 12 pm',
 'lunch happened at 1pm']
```

If you want to ensure having a word boundary or a digit before am/pm (i.e not splitting after words such as "program"):

```
import re

splitlist = re.split(r'(?:(?<=\d[ap]m)|(?<=\b[ap]m))\s+', st)
```

Example:

```
['Walking happened at 8 am',
 'breakfast happened at 9am',
 'baseball happened at 12 pm',
 'beginning of program happened at 1pm']
```