# Sort so first element in pair occurs before matching second element in pair

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a list of pairs of values that I will use later for text substitutions. The code should not make one substitution, and then a second substitution on the same element. So I want to sort the pairs of the substitution list to prevent more than one substitution.

The program searches through text. When it finds text matching the first element in the substitution pairs, it replaces it with the second element.

A snippet of my substitution list looks like this:

```
subst_list = [
['AI_010306', 'AI_010307'],
['AI_010307', 'AI_010308'],
['AI_010310', 'AI_010309'],
['AI_010311', 'AI_010310']]
```

A snippet of the original text to be replaced looks like this:
`old_text = "AI_010306 AI_010307 AI_010310 AI_010311"`

The desired new text would be:
`new_text = "AI_010307 AI_010308 AI_010309 AI_010310"`

I would like the substitution list to look like this:

```
subst_list = [
['AI_010307', 'AI_010308'],
['AI_010306', 'AI_010307'],
['AI_010310', 'AI_010309'],
['AI_010311', 'AI_010310']]
```

If a value occurs in both the first element set and the second element set, the pair with the value in the first position should be sorted earlier in the list.

I don't want to substitute 'AI_010306' -> 'AI_010307' and then 'AI_010307' -> 'AI_010308'.

I this case, there is no risk of a string in one set occurring as a sub-string of the other set.

I tried sorting by the first element and I tried sorting by the second element, but neither satisfies the condition. So, in the mean time, I have been sorting these lines by hand.

Here is the substitution program:

```
with open("source.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        new_line = line.rstrip()
        for s in subst_list:
            new_line = new_line.replace(s[0], s[1])
        print(new_line.rstrip())
```

I also tried using a dictionary instead of a list, but the result is the same.

```
with open("source.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        new_line = line.rstrip()
        for s in subst_dict:
            new_line = new_line.replace(s, subst_dict[s])
        print(new_line.rstrip())
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Rather than using a substitution list, you should be using a dictionary.  Then this problem disappears:  You look in the dictionary, and if the key exists, you substitute that element.  Then you move on to the next element.

Comment: The main point is to substitute all tokens in input text in one pass. If you do that, the order of subst_list does not matter. As @TomKarzes suggested, dictionary is most convenient, but the focus of the fix is processing input in one pass.

Comment: do a regex search for `\w+` and a replace function that calculates the replace text using a dictionary lookup, use the same text if key not found, use the variant that does not modify/update the dictionary if key not found

Comment: Your dictionary attempt changes nothing - you still have a multi-pass algorithm, but the order of the rules comes from the dictionary -> as of python 3.7, the declaration order is kept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: Do you have circular rules like @Lesiak showed (A -> B, B -> C, C -> A)?

Comment: The substitution list does not have any circular rules. Yes, that would be a problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topological-sort

Comment: I expect that topological sort may be the correct answer, but this is a new concept for me and I am working to understand it and to get some code together to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking at the question. I was able to find something that works, but I haven't stress tested it yet. It did work for my use case. The problem with the other suggestions is in the assumption that the original tokens are easy to find in the source text. The only way to reliably find them, so far, has been to see if they exist in the substitution list. I guess it's my fault for oversimplifying the example text.

Here is what works and I'd be interested in improvements.

```
def reorder_list(subst_list):
    swap_made = True
    while swap_made:
        swap_made = False
        for i, s in enumerate(subst_list):
            for j, t in enumerate(subst_list):
                if s[0] == t[1] and j < i:
                    move_item = subst_list.pop(i)
                    subst_list = subst_list[:j] + [move_item] + subst_list[j:]
                    swap_made = True
                    break
            if swap_made:
                break
    return subst_list
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, the problem is that you process your substitutions in multiple passes. For each defined substitution, you replace `subSource` with `subTarget` globally in the input string.
As you noticed the problem arises when you have the following rules: `A -> B`, `B -> C`. Now, when processing with multiple passes, the order of rules start to matter.

Note that your proposal to keep the rules in some order is not enough in general: with input `ABC` and rules: `A -> B`, `B -> C`, `C -> A` there is no order which works for multi-pass algorithm and gives the desired output `BCA`

Instead, **transform your text in one pass**:

- tokenize it. Note: remember to keep the separators: [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)
- for each token, use a substitution if defined, or same token if no substitution exists
- join the transformed tokens

```py
import re
from typing import Dict


def replace_tokens(input_text: str, substitutions: Dict[str, str]) -> str:
    input_tokens = re.split('(\\s+)', input_text)
    new_tokens = [substitutions.get(token, token) for token in input_tokens]
    return "".join(new_tokens)


substitutions_dict = {
    'AI_010306': 'AI_010307',
    'AI_010307': 'AI_010308',
    'AI_010310': 'AI_010309',
    'AI_010311': 'AI_010310'
}

old_text = "AI_010306 AI_010307 AI_010310 AI_010311"

print(replace_tokens(old_text, substitutions_dict))
```

In one-pass algorithm the order of substitution rules does not matter at all, so you can use the most convenient data structure - a dictionary.