# Adding two blank lines and preserving text wrap in Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently working on a Python script using the Python Imaging Library (PIL) to add text to an image. My goal is to split the input text at period-space combinations, retain the combinations, and add two blank lines between each segment.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import textwrap
```

I attempted to modify a Python script for adding text to an image. The goal was to split the text at the period-space combination ('. '), retain the combination, and add two lines.

I used the textwrap module to wrap lines of text.

```
import textwrap

# Example text
text = "This is a sample text that needs wrapping."

# Wrap lines using textwrap
wrapped_text = textwrap.wrap(text, width=20)
```

Split each line at the period-space combination using .split('. ').

```
# Example line
line = "This is a sentence. Another sentence. Yet another sentence."

# Splitting at period-space combination
segments = line.split('. ')
```

Adjusted the y-coordinate for line spacing between segments and lines.

```
# Example y-coordinate and line spacing
y_position = 100
line_spacing = 20

# Adjusting y-coordinate for line spacing between segments
for j, segment in enumerate(segments):
    if j > 0:
        y_position += line_spacing
```

I expected the modified script to split the text at the period-space combination ('. '), retain the combination, and add two lines while maintaining proper text wrapping.

Unfortunately, the modified script deleted the period-space combination instead of retaining it. Despite attempting various adjustments, including different splitting techniques and line spacing modifications, the issue persists.

Comment: [Why did you expect it to retain the delimiter?](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). And of course: does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)