# How to read a dict from file that contains regex

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to read dict values from a config file that contain regular expressions. One solution I saw was to read as json and convert. I tried this solution but it doesn't work:

My file contains this dict:

```
{"my_word":"word\s"}
```

Then in the script:

```
import json

with open('config_dict.ini') as f:
    data = f.read()

js = json.loads(data)
print(js)
```

But I get the error "JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape". So I tried to escape the slash:

```
{"my_word":"word\\s"}
```

And there's no error but it reads the dict as is, which isn't going to work when I use the regex.

Is there another way to read a dict? It doesn't have to include json.

Edit: I tried this solution but it doesn't work. And anyway it's going to be messy if I have to add so many escapes to the regex.

[How to handle regex string in JSON file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497852/how-to-handle-regex-string-in-json-file-with-python)

Comment: Does it have to be JSON? If you just read in a line of text from a file you won't need to worry about escaping etc.

Comment: @match no, that JSON solution didn't work for me. And anyway it's gonna be very messy if I have to add many escape slashes.

Comment: I see solutions for ast but I am unable to pip install. Getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized "import ast" does what I need.